# How to create a hover effect in a newsletter?

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I'm creating a newsletter, and i want to have panels that change background-color on mouse over.
Seeing as the newsletter wont have a head, I am defining all styles inline. I'm pretty sure most popular mail clients will block JS. So I was wondering if I can define a hover effect in the style attribute. Or is there any other solution to achieve this effect?
Peace

Comment: Although one would think css support is common in mail clients, you should reconsider: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

http://www.xavierfrenette.com/articles/css-support-in-webmail/

Comment: @nc3b: cool, could have added this to an answer and I'd accept that I can't use pseudo inline

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you checked these?

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/design-perfect-newsletter/

The latter article says this:

> Hover effects are not supported in Outlook 2007/2010, Gmail, iOS or Android. You may still want to include the a:hover style for all supporting clients: Outlook 2000/2003, Hotmail, Apple Mail, and Yahoo! mail ...

Javascript is a no-go. There is really no solution to this, some will accept :hover, some not. From that first link you can see which will and which will not.

Answer (score 0):

I you are certain your css will not be removed, you can use a hover and a background-color property

```
.panel:hover {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

Also it does not seem possible to [use a pseudo-selector in an inline style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css), so that might be a stopper:

Comment: I am certain the CSS is removed, i've been testing a lot