# Setting an event with DOM javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, events, onclick, element

I am trying to set an event in JavaScript but it is not really working.  I am pretty sure I am doing it correctly too.

```
// in index.htm:
function foo() {
  // Load gets code from a php file via ajax
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = load('phppage.php');
  document.getElementById('element').onClick = func;
}

// in lib.js:
function func() { alert('Working'); }
```

Unfortunately... it never alerts 'Working'.  I have Google Chrome and I even inspected the element in the developer tools and found that the `onClick` property was infact `func()`... I don't understand why this wont work.

I do have extensive use of ajax. The element 'element' is actually loaded with ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing it to "onclick"

Comment: javascript function names are case-sensitive, so +1 for you!

Comment: @glambalazas, right, it's a property, not a function name. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML attributes** *are not*, but **javascript properties** *are* **case-sensitive**. You need to use `onclick` to set the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think the onclick property is lowercase.
However, you should use event attaching methods.

```
element.addEventListener('click',func);
```

(and attachEvent for Internet Explorer)

Answer (score -2):

Of course, there are plenty of frameworks out there to handle the cross browser issues for doing this, such as:

[ExtJS](http://sencha.com/products/extjs)

[JQuery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: like changing a character? Oh I'm sure there are plenty of them.. It has nothing to do with browsers. Case-sensitivity is a part of the language.

Comment: What on Earth are you talking about? Everyone knows that using inline handlers is poor practice (http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

Heck, you even advocate the same thing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes/3142741#3142741

Frameworks abstract away the differences in the event models, for example shared/singleton event object or the difference between addEventListener and attachEvent. Seems you have something stuck in your behind ;)