# change image source with javascript - what's wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
<IMG onmouseover="document.swap2.src='http://www.grlf.com/pics/png';" id="brewmp" alt=Brew src=changeOSImage() width=26 height=24>


function changeOSImage() {
    var mp_os = "x";

    if (mp_os) == "Brew MP") {
        document.getElementById("brewmp").src = "http://www.greengo-cellular.com/ebay_files/images/features_n_02.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("brewmp").src = "http://www.greengo-cellular.com/ebay_files/images/features_02.png";
    }
};
```

For some reason instead of changing the url, the url displays the function name inside of it (therefore leading to nowhere). What have I done wrong?

Comment: Background read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes

Comment: Formatting the code when posting a question also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, the src of your image cannot be a function. Also I cannot see what document.swap2 actually refers to in your code. try something like

```
  <img id="brewmp" src="http://www.grlf.com/pics/png" />

  <script>
  window.onload = (function(){
         var mp_os = 'x';
         document.getElementById('brewmp').onmouseover = (function(){
              this.src = 'path/to/different/image';
         });
  });
  </script>
```

I'm not sure what mp_os is referring to in your initial code as it's set as x and you never change it, plus it is defined within the scope of your function which means it will always be 'x' in this case.The above should give you a good starting point to add your "if" statement into though, but you should declare var mp_os outside of the function

Answer (score 3):

You can not specify a function at the `src` attribute of an image.

Try putting the `changeOSImage()` function at the `onload` event of the document, or calling it from some other function.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answers, you have an extra ) in your if statement. Try this:

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/Ln7KG/)

JavaScript (added inside `<head></head>`):

```
<script>
var mp_os = '';

function changeImage(){

    if (mp_os == "Brew MP") {
        mp_os = "x";
        document.getElementById("brewmp").src = "http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/75/i_like_buttons_3a/512/perspective_button_stop.png";
    } else {
        mp_os = "Brew MP";
        document.getElementById("brewmp").src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Perspective-Button-Go-icon.png";
    }

}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<img onmouseover="changeImage()" onmouseout="changeImage()" id="brewmp" alt="Brew" src="http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/75/i_like_buttons_3a/512/perspective_button_stop.png" width="20%">
```