# Form validation using JavaScript always true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, validation

Added some more text because stackoverflow says there's too much code

HTML

```
<form name="contact">
    <fieldset>
        <label class="labelone" for="naam">Naam:</label>
        <input name="naam">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email">
        <label for="boodschap">Boodschap:</label>
        <textarea name="boodschap"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input class="btn" type="button" onClick="valideren()" value="Verzenden" />
        <div id="resultaat"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function valideren() {
    if (document.getElementsByName('naam').value != '' && document.getElementsByName('email').value != '' && document.getElementsByName('boodschap').value != '') {
        document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = "De e-mail werd verstuurd";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = "Gelieve alle velden in te vullen!";
    }
}
```

Why does this always return true?

Thanks in advance!

Stijn

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns a NodeList not a Node. You have to loop.

Comment: It helps to format the code in your question so that it is readable.

Comment: Provide supporting code when asking a question, a jsfiddle of your issue always helps too. This means we do not need to guess or create a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Background read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes

Comment: Ok, i'll bare that in mind the next time I ask a question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName), you will see that `document.getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, not a single `Node`.

**[Click for live working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/Y3E3Z/7/)**

```
var naam = document.getElementsByName('naam')[0].value,
    email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value,
    boodschap = document.getElementsByName('boodschap')[0].value,
    target = document.getElementById('resultaat');
```

Now:

```
if (naam.length && email.length && boodschap.length) {
    target.innerHTML += "valid";
} else {
    target.innerHTML += "invalid";
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice response! Even though it keeps returning invalid, when all fields are filled in...

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration the question updates and other information pointed to about how to style your code better. Here is a possible solution.

HTML

```
<form name="contact">
    <fieldset>
        <label class="labelone" for="naam">Naam:</label>
        <input name="naam">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email">
        <label for="boodschap">Boodschap:</label>
        <textarea name="boodschap"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input id="validateButton" class="btn" type="button" value="Verzenden" />
        <div id="resultaat"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function valideren() {
    var form = this.parentNode.parentNode,
        resultaat = document.getElementById('resultaat');

    if (form.naam.value !== '' && form.email.value !== '' && form.boodschap.value !== '') {
        resultaat.textContent = "De e-mail werd verstuurd";
    } else {
        resultaat.textContent = "Gelieve alle velden in te vullen!";
    }
}

document.getElementById('validateButton').addEventListener("click", valideren, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VzZkJ/)

I added an "id" to the button just to make it easier to locate in the jsfiddle, of course you can use alternative methods to find it in the DOM.

Some reference material.

[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById)

[document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName)

[Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

[Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)