# Fade in a div when hovered over another div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I am trying to make `div2` and `div3` appear when I hover over `div1`.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AbEZm/

HTML:

```
<div onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide()">Div 1 Content</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none;>Div 2 Content</div>
<div id="div3" style="display: none;>Div 3 Content</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById('div2', 'div3').style.display = 'block';
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

But these functions do not make div2 and div3 appear.  What is wrong?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with that code. You haven't closed your style attributes.  You can't call `getElementById` with two parameters.

Comment: @JamesMontagne ohhh. yeah i'm kinda new to this. so thanks. i'll fix that now.

Comment: I would call what you have (and accepted) "Pop-in" rather than "Fade-in", but hey-ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass two arguments to `getElementById`. Also your HTML was invalid because you did not close the `"` for the `style` attribute.

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve exactly, however I modified your code to kinda make it work...

http://jsfiddle.net/AbEZm/2/

However a better alternative would be to make use of the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) CSS selector.

Comment: thank-you that was what I was trying to do. yeah I know I should revise the basics. but thanks again!

Comment: @Elvain Although his answer does work, I highly suggest taking a look at my answer. Javascript is not needed for something like this, use CSS, I've also included fading.

Comment: @plalx how do I make it so that you could also hover over the hidden divs once its activated by the visible div?

Comment: Consider this rather than inline event handlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using javascript, use css.

```
HTML:
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>

CSS:

#div2{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity .4s; /* Opera */
}
#div1:hover + #div2{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. But I wanted to use javascript instead of css so yeah. but thanks!!

Comment: @Elvain I'm curious, why are you using Javascript to do this?

Comment: because I needed to implement three objects that involves javascript in my website so I chose to do this

Comment: @Elvain For a class? That's cool, good luck in the class if you're taking one :P

Comment: Gotta love CSS, and CSS3 transition: +1