# How can you change the color of a label in a form?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, styles

I have the following code,

HTML

```
<label for="fName">First Name<sup>*</sup></label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="fName" id="fName" value='' required/>
```

JavaScript

```
var fName = document.getElementById("fName");
fName.label.style.color="red";
```

Is this a valid way to change the color or the label or does it need it's own id?

Thanks for the help!
Clarification, the color needs to change if the field is empty on the form submit.

Comment: you may simply achieve this by using CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/WEBpe/ do you really want to use JS specifically?

Comment: Yeah the javascript is triggered when the user tries to submit the form to change the fields to alert them to empty field. I've tried the require, but it's not functional in Safari.

Comment: @Pravin Waychal : Is it possible to change the label color when the field is invalid without javascript. tried different options,couldn't achieve it.

Comment: @user1645290 Check this http://html5doctor.com/css3-pseudo-classes-and-html5-forms/ e.g. input:required + label{ color: red; } I don't this so there is way in css you can put style on previous element hence for this case label should be after input

Answer (score 2):

Your code is valid for changing attribute `color`. But I don't think your code will change colour of your label. If this style unique for that element you can use a `id` for `label` and make same kind script to change color for label too. I think it would be great if you define a `class` in `css` and add this class name using JavaScript,Code for that follows.

```
document.getElementById('id').classList.add('class');
document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('class');
```

If your can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com)  framework. It will save lots of time.

Comment: Using a class to change a color is usually the best idea. Because you can adjust the css not the javascript code.  I would also recommend using the jQuery framework also.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this very complete answer:
[Javascript change color of text and background to input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625618/javascript-change-color-of-text-and-background-to-input-value)

Comment: this is not what the OP wants, he wants something programmatical, such as by setting the label color to red when the corresponding field is invalid

Comment: You're right! the question wasn't edited yet when I answered.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is not any short and direct way to access the attached label corresponding to an input field using javascript. You can access the attached label via CSS (with some tweaks in layout) but in javascript, you have to set up a few lines of code. To use this code, the layout also has a requirement that all the attached label should go before the input field (spaces in between are allowed). This code just use the `previousSibling` property of a DOM element with some other DOM stuffs. Here is the detail:

```
function getLabelFromInputID(inputID){
   var prevSib = document.getElementById(inputID).previousSibling;
   //remove the spaces if any exists
   while(prevSib.nodeName=='#text') prevSib=prevSib.previousSibling;
   if(prevSib.getAttribute('for') != inputID) prevSib = null;
   return prevSib;
}
```

Use the `getLabelFromInputID` function to access the attached label from the corresponding input field's ID. Note that the label should have `for` attribute set-up correctly (this is the standard and common practice).

Here is the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CUdTe/5/). In this demo, you just try clicking on the page to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

using css

```
form label{color:red};
```

using javascript

```
<label for="fName" class="lbl">First Name<sup>*</sup></label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="fName" id="fName" value='' required/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.lbl').css('color','red');
    });
</script>
```

or simple javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("lbl").style.color="red";
```

Comment: Note, your "javascript" is not javascript, but jquery. You should note that, especially since the OP does not mention jquery (also, why have the OP download a 100kb file just to manipulate a single style??)

Comment: this code is just an example you can add your jquery from your server.

and 

 i have written 3 options to make it and it can be done using CSS as well as core JAVASCRIPT...

 but normally all designer uses jquery for more comfort.

:)

Comment: @Tirthrajsinh Parmar : How to use with css option when the element is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on your use case. If you are simply trying to style the element red statically, you should define a css class (e.g. `red-label { color: red; }) and apply that class to the label.

If you are trying to dynamically set the color to red (e.g. upon a form validation error), you'll need to target the label using a query selector of some sort.

```
function makeLabelRedDirectly() {
  document.getElementById('fNameLabel').style.color = 'red';
}

function makeLabelRedViaClass() {
  // Note you can use the more robust `element.classList` with modern browsers
  // document.getElementById('fNameLabel').classList.add('red-label');
  document.getElementById('fNameLabel').className += ' red-label' ;
}
```

The examples above use `document.getElementById` to target the element. You could also opt to use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) or a library like jQuery to target the labels.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/calol/1

Answer (score 0):

An `input` element does not have a `label` property or another way to directly refer to its label. You need to assign an `id` to the `label` element or otherwise find a way to access it. You could traverse all `label` elements on a page and use the one with a `for` property matching the `input` element, but it’s probably easier to just use `id` for it.