# React.js: contentEditable div not rendering nested span elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a contentEditable div where I am trying to update the colors of words that the user types into it onChange. When I detect a word that I want to be colored, I wrap it in a `<span>` element.

The issue is, the `<span>` elements aren't being properly rendered, and the raw HTML of the span elements are being displayed like this:

`bla bla bla <span class="text-primary">keyword with color</span> bla bla bla`.

How do I fix this? Is this something to do with React?

This is the code I'm using to generate the text that goes inside the contentEditable div. I store the result in a variable in `render()` and directly pass it into the contentEditable div with `{text}`.

```
function formatDateKeywords(name, keyword) {
  var startIndex = name.indexOf(keyword);
  var endIndex = startIndex + keyword.length;
  var res =
    name.substring(0, startIndex) +
    "<span class='text-primary'>" +
    keyword +
    "</span>" +
    name.substring(endIndex, name.length);

  return res;
}
```

This is what the div looks like:

```
<div
    contentEditable="true"
    suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
    id="addItemInput"
    data-placeholder={placeholder}
    className="form-control text-left editable"
    type="text"
    onInput={(e) => this.handleInput(e)}
    onKeyDown={(e) => this.keyPress(e)}
>
    {formattedText}
</div>
```

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625618/javascript-change-color-of-text-and-background-to-input-value

Comment: Can you provide the code, which you have run to change the color of text, so that it would be easy to resolve your issue ?

Comment: I don't want to change the color of the whole contentEditable div element, just specific words inside it. That's why I'm wrapping the words in <span>, but alas the span elements aren't getting rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in reactjs you have to use JSX to add tag into content:
i use React.Fragment to avoid adding unused tag.

```
function formatDateKeywords(name, keyword) {
  var startIndex = name.indexOf(keyword);
  var endIndex = startIndex + keyword.length;
  var res = <>
        {name.substring(0, startIndex)}
        <span class='text-primary'>{keyword}</span>
        {name.substring(endIndex, name.length)}
    </>;

  return res;
}
```