# Is CSS classes for every different style a good idea?

Tags: html, css, class

Currently in my website I have css classes for every time the style changes, for instance, for the subheading of the tagline I have `.subheading{font-size:20px;}` I am having doubts as to whether this is a good plan or not. For short one rule classes should I just use the style attribute in html, or is there a different way of approaching this all together?

Comment: Why have a class called `subheading`? Is there another way to select the elements that should have that style? For example, can you replace `.subheading` with `h2` or `article > h1`?

Comment: Do you want to change one line of code, or potentially hundreds? CSS exists for that very reason.

Comment: Look at the http://smacss.com/ site.  The author offers both a free ebook and a commercial one, describing how to structure CSS.  Remmeber, elemts can have more than one class, and they can inherit styling from their containers.

Comment: @bdesham is there any advantage to using h1 or h2 over my own class? Am I doing something wrong there as well?

Comment: @handuel Sit down right now and read [this Wikipedia article about semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML). If your pages don't follow this overall design pattern then [most people would tell you that] you're misusing HTML.

Comment: The reason you'd take bdesham's advice is so that you don't have to add any classes to your markup. If you can use a selector combination that's unique to that situation, you can make your change with one line of CSS and nothing else.

Comment: If it is a headline and h1-h6 have the semantic meaning of *headline*, why would you not use h1-h6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inline Styles vs Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it. But, consider if several classes contain many of the same styles, then why not nest them within a parent class and apply the common styles to the parent so that they are inherited by the children. For example, if you have the following:

```
.para{ color: white; font-size: 2em;}
.subhead{ color: white; font-size: 3em;}
.heading{ color: white; font-size: 4em;}
```

It is better practice to do this:

```
.text {color:white;}
.para{font-size: 2em;}
.subhead{font-size: 3em;}
.heading{font-size: 4em;}
```

Then the html:

```
<div class='text'>
    <div class='para'> </div>
    <div class='subhead'> </div>
    <div class='heading'> </div>
</div>
```

As I've become more familiar with styling html, I've found a good practice is to never be scared to add another `<div>` element where necessary - it can help ease and standardize your formatting a lot.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, I am just asking if it is a good idea.

Comment: Yep. It's a good idea. Keep things clean.

Comment: What most of the people are complaining about is if you're combining your style into your html. Use html to cleanly separate regions of the page into logical chunks. Then use CSS to style those logical chunks. If you cannot form clean CSS or clean HTML then revise until they are both pretty clean.

Comment: So much wrong here in the markup.

Comment: It's an example. I didn't say it's how you should go about setting font-sizes and colors.