# Aligning font-awesome icons to center

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>         
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--end row-->
    </div><!--end container-->
</section>
```

This is my code. I intend to center the font awesome icons to the center in their respective columns but I'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You can move `text-center` to your column `<div>`, then all the text in this `<div>` will be centered (the first row in my example).
2. You can add extra `<div>` with class `text-center` and move your icon inside it (the second row in my example).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--end row-->
    </div><!--end container-->
</section>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/gwe7a2e6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will work:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align:center;">
      <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>         
      <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Solias you shouldn't use inline styles in CSS, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes) for the explanation. Use `text-center` class instead, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42315688/2570353).

Comment: ahh, i will look through this once again. I was in a hurry and was looking for a quick fix so; will incorporate the text-center class now and see how it pans out.

Answer (score 0):

```
.center{
text-align:center;
width:50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="center"><i class="fa fa-book fa-3x text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

This brings it to the middle as the way u wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <section>
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <p>Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam</p>
             </div>
          </div><!--end row-->
       </div><!--end container-->
    </section>
```

Put the font awesome icon into a separate div and apply "text-center" class. It will align font-awesome icons to center.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simplest way:

```
<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-book fa-3x text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```