# How to change the font color of few string in p tag for a dynamic string

Tags: html, angular

I have a list which needs to displayed on a pop up. Suppose my list contains below information

row 1: Name mismatch error

row 2: Expecting numbers

Row 3: mandatory field

I want the row1, row 2 , row 3 to be in red and rest of the text in black

TS:

```
 getMessages()
 {
  var msg :string[] = [];
  var separatedMsg:any[];
  msg = this.getErrorMessage(this.messages); 
  var msgBody = document.getElementById("msgBody");
  msgBody.innerHTML="";
  for(var i=0;i<msg.length;i++)
   {
   separatedMsg=msg[i].split(":")
   var pElement:any = document.createElement("p"); 
   var emElement:any = document.createElement("em");
   emElement.innerHTML =separatedMsg[0];
   pElement.innerHTML =  emElement.innerHTML+separatedMsg[1]+'\n';
   emElement.style.color ="Red"
   pElement.style.color = "Black"
   msgBody.appendChild(pElement)
    }
 }
```

with this I get all the text in black, my idea was to split the string at : and make first half as em tag and second half as P tag. I'm not sure how to append both this tag.
How do I achieve this ?

Comment: is this angular?

Comment: Did you forgot to appendChild(emElement)? You missed msgBody.appendChild(emElement); before to msgBody.appendChild(pElement). Let me know if it works?

Comment: Why don't you create that html in the template directly? It'd be much easier than using plain dom manipulation

Answer (score 0):

a) Perhaps it's easier to set an innerHTML as string:

```
msgBody.innerHTML='<div class="msg-div">test<p class="msg-p">test2 <span class="msg-what-ever">word</span></p></div>';
```

b) You can use classes instead of inline style. See [inline-styles-vs-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/whats-the-difference-between-inline-styles-vs-classes)

```
.msg-div {color: green;}
.msg-p {color: red;}
.msg-what-ever {color: blue;}
```