# Can I define a rollover CSS style in-line?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Is it possible to do this:

```
<a href="#">link</a>

a{ color: red; }
a:hover{ color: blue; }
```

As inline?

```
<a href="#" style="color: red; ....;">link</a>
```

Comment: can't uses selectors in line sorry

Comment: Have you written a test page and tried to do this?  Nevermind - seems the answer is no anyway. :)

Comment: @Ibu Good find mate, sadly I haven't been using this site long enough to memorize the entirety of its content. If what I'm looking for doesn't appear in the related questions when I ask, then it seems quicker to ask myself. Thanks though, answered my question.

Comment: @Marty There is a handy search box in the top right corner. I managed to use it several times with great success :). Noone has been here long enough to memorize the site's contents.

Comment: If people wanted to use search boxes to solve everything; wouldn't they just use Google?

Comment: @Marty Wallace: Please don't take it as something against your question, think of it as a way to help the next guy typing in the question or search box. Now the questions are linked as well. Don't worry about it - the question is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `style=""` allows to define only list of style properties. No CSS selectors are allowed there.