# Inline CSS for anchor tag and hover

Tags: css

I'm under the impression that changing an anchor tag on hover can be done like this:

```
a:hover {background: #FFDD00;}
a:hover {color: #AAAAAA;}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Now, for some convoluted reason, I can't put that code in a style sheet, I have to put it in the actual HTML. How would I do that?

```
<a href="..." style="___???___">...</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to do that.

Inline CSS can't touch pseudo-classes such as `:hover`.

I'm guessing the reason you want to do this is because you can only edit the `<body>` of the HTML (for whatever reason). What you *can* do is add a `style` element:

```
<style>
a:hover {
    background: #FFDD00;
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
</style>

<a href="#">...</a>
```

Having a `style` element outside the `<head>` is not valid HTML, but (crucially) it does work in all browsers.

Comment: I needed this to set hover style for links inside an e-mail... unfortunately gmail removes style tags, and also external style references, and also javascripts... so there is no hope?

Comment: Closing `<style>` tag needs to have a forward slash; `</style>`

Answer (score 8):

If you can't toss your hover CSS into a  tag, then the best way to handle this is going to be JavaScript. I wouldn't ordinarily call this a good approach, but it sounds like your hands are tied here.

```
<a href="..."
   onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffdd00';this.style.color='#aaaaaa'"
   onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';this.style.color='inherit'">
...
</a>
```

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 6):

Found this in an old forum and it seems to work great :)

```
<a href="###" style="text-decoration: none;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = 'none'">###</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put both styles in the same block, like this.

```
a:hover {
    background: #FFDD00;
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

And if you cannot use an external stylesheet, you can add a style block to the head of your page...

```
    ...
    <style>
        a:hover {
            background: #FFDD00;
            color: #AAAAAA;
        }
    </style>
</head>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't apply psudo-classes inline, but you can do this with javascript inline.

e.g.

```
<a href="..." onmouseover="this.style.color = 'red'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to follow the suggestions put forth above in an external style sheet, but for whatever reason you really need to do it, try this:

a href="" style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;"