# How can i add "focus" directly by the style tag in html?

Tags: html, css

How can i add "focus" directly by the style tag in html?
for ex: (I cant use stylesheet or javascript for this issue, since its inside mail)
HTML Code:

```
<a href="#" style="a:focus { border: 1px solid #000; }">CLICK ME TO SEE THE BOUNDRIES</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<style type="text/css">` tag

```
<style type="text/css">
a.hover{
/*your style here*/
}
</style>
```

or if you want to give style to this particular anchor tag then give the id to this anchor and use

```
<style type="text/css">
#<anchor id>:hover{
/*your style here*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: "DIRECTLY" - "I cant use stylesheet or javascript for this issue, since its inside mail"

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) guide to CSS in emails, you have the ability to use `<style>` tags in the email, but this method is not supported at all by either GMail (both browser and mobile versions).

That being said, there is little to no support for the `hover`, `visited`, and `focus` selectors on any client.

I understand completely that cross-client incompatibility may not be a worthwhile compromise, but just know that this option is out there.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible without using JS and CSS.For reference you can go through this link

[How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

And you can define style tag in mail content body.