# Writing pseudo style propeties to class or style tag of anchor

Tags: asp.net, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Can someone show me an example or correct syntax on how to apply pseudo style propeties directly to class or style property of anchor like this :

```
<a href="#" class="a:link{} a:visited{}..."> Link</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm understanding your question, but if your CSS has something like:

```
a
{
    font-family: sans-serif
}

a:visited
{
    font-family: arial
}
```

Then you wouldn't need any class declarations in your markup for `<a />`.

Likewise, if you had classes like this:

```
.someClass
{
    font-family: sans-serif
}

.anotherClass
{
    font-family: arial
}
```

You would just do:

```
<a href='#' class='someClass anotherClass'>Link</a>
```