# Css Overwrite issue - Change the scope of external styles

Tags: html, css

my website scraped information from ebay products and for the description of the product I get all html. Product description has inline styles and when I open the description of the product in my website, products css ovewrite my css
Normal:

[image]

And after I opened the product description

[image]

Here is anchor style from developer tool

[image]

So I need any idea how to separete ebay product css with my css.
One of the methods that I think is to add `!important` to all my styles, but I don't think this solution is elegant and I want something else. So If you have any suggestion how to solve my issue I will appreciate them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove inline css of an HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383668/remove-inline-css-of-an-html-elements)

Comment: No, I don't want to remove the external css styles, becase It will effect a whole product description, but I want to keep it the same as from ebay.

Comment: hey, can you explain a little more, do u want to keep the styles coming from ebay and your personal styles at the same time? if  not u can use javacsript to remove the inline styles of the html coming from ebay products

Comment: I have two option, ebay Api with php, and second way is node js crawler, the idea that came to my mind, right now is to get all styles attribute from all elements and after that put them to to top of the page with some class, and this way I think will fix my issue

Comment: So what do you want to remove? what do you want to keep?

Comment: Nothing I want to keep both, but my styles to be for the website, and ebay styles to be for  the product description, that's all

Comment: you want some elements to be "immune" from ebay's styles?

Comment: Yes, I want my styles to be "immune"from ebay's styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to update your `css` to be more specific with it's selector, for example if you have a HTML structure which diferentiate the container of the Product Description from eBay like this

```css
.leftbar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: #ccc;
}

a { /*think of this as default link style*/
  color: black;
}

#main div:not(.product-desc) a {  /*more specific selector*/
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

a { /*this one is from eBay*/
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div class='leftbar'>
    <a>Hello</a>
    <a>World</a>
  </div>
  <div class='product-desc'>
    <a>Description</a>
    <a>Product</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use a `:not` selector to define your main style so it won't be disrupted by the eBay style

The more specific your selector is, then your style will be used. But if your selector is the same, then the last rule from top bottom will be applied. So in the above example, the link inside `product-desc` color is set to `green` not `black`

Comment: ok, thank you I will try to do it this way :)

Answer (score 0):

create a custom inline CSS property that you desire in the element to overwrite the default CSS. here is how you create inline CSS for overwriting anchor properties.

Here how you do:
create the icons/text of anchor inside a  element and give inline CSS

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
    <span style="color: #ffffff !important;" >icons</span>
</a>
```

A quick test in Chrome shows that the

```
a:visited * { ... !important}
```

does override the inline style, but adding the !important back to the span works fine.

```
<span style="color: #ffffff !important;" >
```

For understanding it better. Learn here [Overwriting Hover in anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)
[Overwriting visited in anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162362/how-to-write-avisited-in-inline-css)

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all exist style and reset it to default you can use:

```
  all: initial;
```

Comment: hmm, I didn't know about the property "all", thank you, I will read more about it