# Why don't we import css in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have seen many souce codes but I have never ever come across a code which imports any css file within a div. [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515) allows it,

> Importing a style sheet to apply as a scoped style sheet:
>
> ```
> <div class="navigation"
>           style="@import url(navigationstyles.css);">...</div>
> ```

Why do people still not use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That document you link to is a **10-year-old draft**, and far from the latest. Now, if you look at the [latest revision of the Style Attributes spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr), which is a 2010 Candidate Recommendation that covers basically the same inline style declarations that we use every day, you won't find any `@import` rules mentioned anywhere anymore.

This means they took it out, presumably because it didn't make sense in retrospect, or it was difficult to implement, or some other reason entirely.

Comment: Presumably you would import rules so that... uh... yeah, I don't know either. ;-)