# Jquery target dynamically created element with css

Tags: jquery, css

I have some HTML that is dynamically generated by another component. A simplified version could be:

```
<div class="classA">
 <div class="classB">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

The classB element isn't available at (document).ready, but when it's created it's created with some inline CSS which I want to change. Since the element isn't available at (document).ready, I can't just do

```
$('.classB').css('color', 'red');
```

and since the element is created with some inline css, I can't use an ordinary style sheet.

**Question:**

How do I apply CSS with jQuery to an element which isn't available at (document).ready?

Comment: Show code where `.classB` element is added to DOM!

Comment: tried to use `$(this)` in the (onclick)func? this should be your .classB div layer, so u can use `$(this).css('color':'red')`

Comment: Code is from third party software so wouldn't know

Comment: why not just put the css in a css file rather then jquery?

Comment: The element is added after (document).ready, and also with inline CSS. So CSS in a style sheet (even with !important) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically altering the dom means that to include **click events** means you have to attach events to the dom.

try something like

```
$(document).on("click",".classB", function(){
    $('.classB').css('color', 'red');
 });
```

should work for you.

You need to bind the event to a parent element, of which **document** is usually chosen by most.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense! OP has already given which works perfectly, he is just asking when the element having `.classB` is available (means added to DOM) he wants to apply css code on it

Comment: But surely that could be placed on the 'creation' of that element?

Comment: Yup.. that can be that's why added comment over his question!

Comment: My thoughts were that ClassA may *also* be created dynamically, and hence have issues

Comment: I may be wrong but this code is about click to add css? I'd like it applied the moment the element is present.

Comment: @Bo: Do you bac know if it will be given a specific class/id

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean?

Comment: on the creation of your 'element', does it get given an id?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what your asking but i think you are askign for style to be applied to an element as soon as it arrives am i right?

If that is the case have a look into http://api.jquery.com/css/ this should be what you are looking for it is rather simle to use.

This style would allow you to apply effects with css straight to the element on generation. My Jquery might be a bit out not done it in a while

```
$('.classA').css( "background-color" : "red" );
```

This would go in your:

```
$(document).ready(fucntion(){
    //here
});
```

If this is going to generate when the user clicks the page look at the appropriate `onClick` function for you document or for your element here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: The element is not present at that time.

Comment: when it does become available it will apply the css if you embed the first option within the document ready. And i think the equivilent to the click code mentioned in your Question is as follows `$(//YourChoice).click(function(){$('.classB').css('color', 'red');});`

Comment: Are you sure? That's why I examplified with the click -code. You need a different approach if the element isn't available at document ready.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it wasnt to educational to examplify with click-code. I want it automatically, not by click.

Comment: I think this is somewhat what you are trying to achieve  http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Hb4FbVNcCG

Comment: I it hasn't been solved tomorrow will see if anyone at work knows any Jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is not complete but consider following prototype.

You're using some code to append element having `classB` to particular div having `classA` so in this case you need to target that `.classB` using following code.

```
$(".classA").html("<div class='classB'></div>").find(".classB").css("color","red");
```

You can use `.find()` immediately after the creation of an element and apply your css code to it

### [**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fj06pv3q/)

I think this might help you.

Comment: Don't know the code behind element creation so wont work

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to define css in your Javascript unless you have a particularly good reason to do so. It makes the division between logic and styling difficult to maintain.

In your case you seem to want to use a class, which makes sense, so then it will be easy to define the css for that class in a stylesheet. The stylesheet can be defined in the head of your html document or it can be linked to from the head of your html [document](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

You can also inject the html stylesheet later, if you are required to do so. [Add stylesheet to Head using javascript in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833759/add-stylesheet-to-head-using-javascript-in-body)

If you have the class defined in your stylesheet like below, the style will be applied to the element as soon as it is added to the DOM.

```
.classB 
{
color:red;
}
```