# Grails: How to add css styles to page dynamicly?

Tags: grails, gsp

I write plugin, which has taglib like this:

```
class MyTagLib {

    static namespace = "my"

    Closure someWidget = { attrs ->
       // Need somehow add styles to page
       // ...
    }
}
```

I use `asset-pipeline` plugin and can't find any way to add stylesheets dynamicly (into `head` tag).

Base gsp layout of application (not my plugin):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <g:layoutHead/>
    <title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
</head>
<body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <asset:deferredScripts/>
</body>
</html>
```

I need something like that in taglib:

```
g.putItIntoHead(asset.stylesheet(src: 'assets/my.css'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a tag that injects a javascript code that does just that.

```
class MyTagLib {

    static namespace = "my"

    Closure putItIntoHead= { attrs ->
       out << " var head = document.head "; 
       out << " var link = document.createElement('link')";

       out << " link.type = 'text/css'";
       out << " link.rel = 'stylesheet'";
       out << " link.href = '{url}'";

       out << " head.appendChild(link)";
    }
}
```

You can also do it using jquery, ( check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833759/add-stylesheet-to-head-using-javascript-in-body) question for more)

**And You don't necessarily have add it to the head.**

Comment: Thanks! Seems it's most easy way to do that.