# How do I change a button size in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, button, size

I'm using javascript to create buttons in a chrome extension but I can't find a way to change the size of the button, here's the code.

```js
var buttonShort = document.createElement("button");
buttonShort.innerHTML = "Generate Short Password";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(buttonShort);

buttonShort.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  var newWindow = window.open();
  newWindow.document.write("The generated Password is: '" + short() + "'");
  newWindow.focus()
});
```

I need to change the size of the button (mainly the width) so if you have any suggestions, please say. Also if you're going to say use CSS, I don't know how to add a CSS file to a javascript file so please tell me how to do that if you don't mind.

Thanks.

Comment: [This any help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833759/add-stylesheet-to-head-using-javascript-in-body)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `style.width` property before you append the button element to the body, like so :

```js
var buttonShort = document.createElement("button");
buttonShort.innerHTML = "Generate Short Password";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

buttonShort.style.width = '200px'; // setting the width to 200px
buttonShort.style.height = '200px'; // setting the height to 200px
buttonShort.style.background = 'teal'; // setting the background color to teal
buttonShort.style.color = 'white'; // setting the color to white
buttonShort.style.fontSize = '20px'; // setting the font size to 20px

body.appendChild(buttonShort);

buttonShort.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newWindow = window.open();
  newWindow.document.write("The generated Password is: '" + short() + "'");
  newWindow.focus();
});
```

all the other CSS properties are accessible through the `style` object (width, height, color, ...etc)

> **NOTE:** beware of properties like `font-size` you cannot use the `-` as
>   an object key so the way you would go about doing that is by
>   `camelCasing` it like so `fontSize`.

Comment: As @tareq [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47383354/4698558), If you are planning to do more than just changing the width of an element and don't want to do this assignment every time, you may use the `style.cssText` property and assign it to a string that contains normal css.

Like so :
`button.style.cssText = 'width: 20px; color: teal';`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `className` or `cssText` to do so.
If you used className, you need to define the class in CSS.

```js
// By setting css class name
var buttonShort = document.createElement("button");
buttonShort.innerHTML = "Generate Short Password";
// set class name 
buttonShort.className = "button";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(buttonShort);

// Or using JS
var buttonShort = document.createElement("button");
buttonShort.innerHTML = "Generate Short Password 2";
// set CSS name  using js
buttonShort.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; background-color:blue;height: 20px;color:white";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(buttonShort);
```

```css
.button {
 border: 1px solid black ;
 background-color: orange;
 height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following code?

```
var cssString = "{padding: 15px 20px; color: #F00;}";
buttonShort.style.cssText = cssString;
```

Comment: I just had to change a little bit of it but despite that, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

put this into head tag:

```
<style>
p.ex3 {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

and put this into body:

```
<div><p id="demo" class="ex0">Led Off</p></div>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Led 
On"'><p class="ex3">Led On</p></button>
```