# Underlining in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class

Upon the realization that you can't have an inline pseudoclass -- [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css) -- I looked into having Javascript do the same job with the `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events to simulate the `:hover` pseudoclass.  I'm trying to remove the underline from the text when the mouse is above it.  Is there a snippet of Javascript someone can offer that can do that?

I tried `onMouseOver="this.style.textDecoration="none""`, but I think the contrasting quotations are throwing everything off.

Any ideas?

Note: unfortunately, this effect must be achieved without the use of an external or internal stylesheet (inline only).

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use a `style` element? People often assume that because they cannot affect the `head` element. But `style` actually works inside `body` too (even though formal HTML syntax forbids it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this by

```
 onMouseOver="this.style.textDecoration='none';"
```

Comment: This works, but I also found that the semicolon is unnecessary.  Is that just good coding habit?

Comment: It is good coding habit, but for one statement it is unnecessary.  Also you could do `onMouseOver='this.style.textDecoration="none";'` (the reverse of quotes) if you preferred it

Comment: Javascript works without semi-colons at the end of statements. But putting one to explicitly mark the end of statements is always a good practice.

Comment: @CodeMonkey you should use semicolon it is a good coding habit.

Comment: @CodeMonkey i am sure you read the vol7ron and techfoobar advice

Comment: @vol7ron You can even do `onMouseOver="this.style.textDecoration=&quot;none&quot;;"` but that's just getting silly. Really, an alternative solution would be ideal, preferably using traditional CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your answer:

```
<a onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='none';"  onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='underline';">hover me</a>
```

if you're able to use jQuery it would be easier. Just write once the following code. You haven't to change your markup then.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $( function() {
        $('a').hover(
            function() {
                $(this).css('text-decoration','none');
            },
            function() {
                $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
            }
        )
    } );
} (jQuery));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use javascript, but CSS:

```
.underlineHover:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```
<span class="underlineHover">Content</span>
```

**Note**: I used the class `underlineHover`, but be aware that classes should have a semantic meaning instead of styling one.