# How to programatically add a hover style C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

So I'm aware that to add a "regular" style to an object in asp you use:

```
object.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
```

Is there any way to add a style but with the :hover selector? Can't find any useful info skimming the web.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: object.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "background-color:red'"); Not sure if this is going to work. if not you can assign JS function and write it in aspx page. HTH

Comment: Yes I'm aware that you can add attributes and assign js functions. I just want to know if there's an easy hover way (which I don't think there is)

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109967/underlining-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the `:hover` selector. The `:hover` pseudo selector can't be applied/used in inline-styles. `object.Style` applies inline styles. You should be using stylesheets anyway and not inline styles.