# Adding hover action for element in div

Tags: html, hover

I'm making a custom menu on WordPress and added a div style to turn the text into a clickable image.

```
<div style="
    background-image: url('http://www.luchaquest.net/home/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/first.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    width: 195px;
    height: 70px;
"></div>
```

Everything so far is working, but I'd like it to have a hover action as well (should be accomplishable by having a line `background-position: 0 -195px`)  I'm not familiar with this  style of programming at all.

How can I add the hover information into this code all in the same element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Answer (score 1):

Use onmouseover function

```
<div id="divID" onmouseover="javascript:UpdateBackground();" style="
background-image: url('http://www.luchaquest.net/home/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/first.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
width: 195px;
height: 70px;
"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateBackground(){
    alert('before update');
document.getElementById("divID").style.backgroundPosition="center bottom";
    alert('after update');
    }
</script>​
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. I'm having trouble using it myself, but it is setting me on the right direction I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<link type="css/text" rel="stylesheet" href="Name.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="divname" style="
background-image: url('http://www.luchaquest.net/home/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/first.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
width: 195px;
height: 70px;
"></div>
</body>
```

Now, go to your .css file and add:

```
#divname:hover {
background-position:0 -195px;
}
```

Good Luck