# CSS a:hover inline?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have been trying to create a navigation bar for a website I am making, and I want each button to display a difference colour when highlighted. I have used `<ul>` to create the navigation bar. The question is, is there a way to use the "a:hover {background:#;}" as inline CSS on a specific element?

I have tried giving each `<li>` or `<a>` an id and then creating references to them in the internal style sheet, but can't get it to work. Below is what I have so far;

```
#menu {height:37px;display:block;margin:20px auto;border:1px solid;border-radius:5px;margin-left:30px;max-width:550px}
#menu ul {margin:0;padding:0;}
#menu li {float:left;display:block;min-width:110px} 
#menu a {display:block;padding:12px;font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.8); background-color:#5A8A41;border-right:1px solid #1b313d; color:#fff;}  
#menu a:hover {background:#5D80B0;}
...
<div id='menu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>XML</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>SQL</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Java</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>C#</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Just so your aware, I have been using html and CSS for all of 1 week. So I apologise if this is a stupid question. Thanks.

Comment: If your are new in HTML/CSS, I ll recommend you to take a look at Bootstrap here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: `#menu a:after {
    border-color:#6696bd;
}` Won't work `a:after` has no size no border width and you are trying to add `border-color`, which doesn't make sense

Comment: Yea, not sure why that's in there... I think I added it in "trail and error" style whilst playing around and never removed it. Probably best I take that out. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's completely impossible; sorry.

Instead, you can create a CSS class for each color and apply the appropriate class to each link:

```
#menu a.red:hover { background: red; }
```

Comment: Thank you. How would that look in the local html? (ie, what would the class reference looks like on the element?) Sorry again for daft questions.

Comment: @RudiKershaw: `class="red"`

Answer (score 3):

If you use `:nth-child(X)` pseudo class, you can do this without adding a class to every new `li` you add. For this, I had to move the `background-color` to `li` and also added a few other CSS properties, nothing much.

This will be your CSS for adding color:

```
#menu li:nth-child(1):hover { background: red; }
#menu li:nth-child(2):hover { background: blue; }
#menu li:nth-child(3):hover { background: purple; }
#menu li:nth-child(4):hover { background: yellow; }
#menu li:nth-child(5):hover { background: pink; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/chHVE/)

[**+ :nth-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with jquery :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().css({background-color: 'yellow'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems overkill, especially for someone who's only been at this for a week.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the last part. But still it's an alternative, he doesn't have to use it. I know it were impossible for me aswell to implement jquery at start. Best luck anyways.

Comment: I know there are some instances where using style sheets is impossible so this is definitely some useful info. Thank you. Although I will probably give JavaScript a miss for a little while yet.

Comment: You will get into it, just focus on the html and css part for a while then give other languages a go. jQuery is one of the easier coding languages to learn and very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Inline javascript

```
<a href='index.html' onmouseover='this.style.textDecoration="none"' onmouseout='this.style.textDecoration="underline"'>Click Me</a>
```

---

In a [working draft of the CSS2 spe](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515#pseudo-rules)c it was declared that you could use pseudo-classes inline like this:

```
<a href="http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS"
   style="{color: blue; background: white}  /* a+=0 b+=0 c+=0 */
      :visited {color: green}           /* a+=0 b+=1 c+=0 */
      :hover {background: yellow}       /* a+=0 b+=1 c+=0 */
      :visited:hover {color: purple}    /* a+=0 b+=2 c+=0 */
     ">
</a>
```

but it was never implemented in the release of the spec as far as I know.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515#pseudo-rules