# Mouseover effect in HTML signature

Tags: html, css, inline, signature

I am trying to create a mouseover effect whereby text (or an image) will dip to 50% opacity on mouseover.

Because I am creating this for an e-mail signature I am restricted to using inline CSS and HTML only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Answer (score 0):

To date, Outlook (Even 2013) does not support any CSS3 or javascript / jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div id="something">Hello!</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#something:hover
{
   opacity:0.5;
   filter="alpha(opacity=50)";
}
```