# Change <a>'s hover / active color within the element tag

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an e-mail signature (so obviously I don't have an attached .css stylesheet) is there any way to set a link's hover / active color (maybe within the tag?)
Thanks for taking the time to answer :)
Tombs

Duplicate here:
[How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do so within HTML as active and hover are CSS selectors and not attributes. So although you could set the height and width of an object in HTML, you would have to use CSS to use the active and hover selectors.

Like such

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="links" href="#"> Link1 </a></li>
    <li><a class="links" href="#"> Link2 </a></li>
    <li><a class="links" href="#"> Link3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul il a.links:hover{
color: blue;
}

ul il a.links:hover{
color: royalblue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that's what I needed to know. It's impossible without using a CSS stylesheet :)

Comment: You're welcome! Yes CSS is required. It's advisable that you locate the styling outside of the element and externally if possible; which would enable caching; but that's up to your digression as a webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

Half of the mail clients do not support this functionality.

See: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

you may only be able to style the active color, with this being a recommended approach

```
 <a href="http://somesite.com/" style="color:#ff00ff"><span style="color:#ff00ff">this is a link</span></a>
```

style the `<a>` tag as well as wrap it in a similar color style `<span>` tag for reinforcement.

you wont be able to style a hover state with in-line css unfortunately.

source:
http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails/

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<h1 style="---">
```

like

```
<h1 style="color:red">hi</h1>
```