# jquery .css() edit a :hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table that when tr are clicked drops down another table as of right now i have the tr with a hover color in place of banded the rows. I set up the javascript to change the background color when you click the tr but is there a way to edit the css back to the default

```
var parent = $('.surveyResponses');

$('.data[question]', parent).on({
    'click' : function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        $('[question='+clicked.attr('question')+']',parent).eq(1).slideToggle('slow', function(){
            if ( $('[question='+clicked.attr('question')+']',parent).eq(1).css('display') == 'block' ) {
                clicked.css('backgroundColor', '#535353');
            }
            else{
                clicked.css('backgroundColor', '#747373');
                clicked.css('backgroundColor:hover', '#535353');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

if possible i would not want to make a jquery hover event

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Des58/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes: [you can't do inline hover events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css).

Example:

```
var elem = $("#elem");

if (mybool)
    elem.removeClass("a").addClass("b");
else
   elem.removeClass("b").addClass("a");
```

I hope I'm understanding you correctly.