# How to implement :hover function directly into a style="" tag

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to change the :hover state for a tr object - but only one tr object, not the hover state for the rest.

The js-fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lgs12pof/1/

I am trying to not make the tr tag's background, where it says bar, change. I am looking for a css hack which i can use in the style"" element, and this way not make it change background color on hover.

I have tried the following, but this does not change the hover state:

```
<tr style="background-color:none !important">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div>Bar</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you are asking. Please re-format your question.

Comment: You need to use CSS- you can't use `:hover` in the style attribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Lgs12pof/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't. Why not use an ID?

```
<tr style="background-color:none !important" id="aRow">
       <td colspan="5">
           <div>Bar</div>
        </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
#aRow:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```