# CSS content property : how to add it as a html style attribute?

Tags: html, css

I found this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_after

but instead of p having a separate css stylesheet, I want to do it in one like:

```
<p style = ":before:content: HELLO">My name is Donald</p>
```

OR

```
<p style = :before {content: HELLO}>I live in Ducksburg</p>
```

Is something like this possible? What is a correct way of doing it? I'm trying to use 'content' CSS property if possible.

Comment: You can have it as embedded style <style> ... </style> if you want.

Comment: No, that is not possible using inline styles. (If you want it “inline”, you could make it _actual_ content of the element in the first place …)

Comment: However you set the `content` property, its value needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set such properties inline.

There was a method in the past, but it no longer works in modern browsers.

[How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css/9884099#9884099)