# hover property in CSS doesn't work when I have an inline styles

Tags: css

I was work on a HTML document and I wanted to use the hover property for a 
HTML:
div element but it didn't work. here the HTML div and the CSS style I used

```
<div style="opacity: 0.8; background-color: #559FED; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 0px 100px;">
   <p style="font-size: 4em; font-family: verdana; font-weight: blod; text-align: center; color: rgba(112,79,196,1); text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000; padding: 10px;"> Special Effects</p>
</div>
```

and in the internal CSS style CSS:

```
div:hover {background-color: red;}
```

But it didn't work till I deleted the style from the div element and created a HTML element selector in the internal style like this:

```
    div {opacity: 0.8; background-color: #559FED; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 0px 100px;}
    div:hover {background-color: red;}
```

then it worked, but can anyone tell me why it didn't work the first time ?

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7zjsdzyq/

Comment: May be answer to your Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css @Taro_NAZA

Comment: @Taro_Naza My pleasure dear

Comment: @afelixj it works but adding !important  ... thanks

Answer (score 3):

Inline style have the highest priority. If you need to override in CSS, need to use `!important`

```
div:hover {background-color: red !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles can be overridden by `!important`, as they take up more importance.

```
div:hover {background-color: red !important;}
```

Something a bit about the specificity.

[image]

Since you have the `style` attribute, it overrides all the other things! It is a *sin* to use `!important`:

[image]