# Change hover color on ::after?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm unable to change the color of a hover on a `::after`.
I was able to change the color of the `::after` to red from black without hover.

The `::after` is actually an arrow transformed from previous CSS coding. It's supposed to point the `<span>Issues</span>` expanding a drop down menu.

```css
.sf-with-ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #DFEEFF;
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

/*top menu issues*/
.nav-menu-item-357 .sf-with-ul span{
  color:#E81717;
}
.nav-menu-item-357 .main-menu-link.sf-with-ul::after {
  border-top-color:#E81717;
}
/*THIS 3rd LINE DOES NOT WORK:*/
.nav-menu-item-357 .main-menu-link.sf-with-ul:hover:after {
  border-top-color:#E81717;
}
```

```html
<ul style="position: relative;">
    <li class="nav-menu-item-357 main-menu-item  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0 new_dropdown_style menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
        <a href="#" class="menu-link main-menu-link sf-with-ul">    
            <span>Issues</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You know that `::after` is a pseudo element right? You don't actually put `::after` in your HTML markup. Also, you should include the triangle CSS so we can verify the issue.

Comment: I have edited the post to include more about this triangle. I don't even know where to find the file to change this PHP/HTML :/

Comment: I've edited your code snippet so that the triangle code actually applies to the correct element. Please take care to make sure that your [mcve]s are both ***complete*** and ***verifiable***. However, the only issue that I see why the color of the triangle isn't changing, is well... you didn't change the color. The hover color is the same color as the static color.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code works (3rd line).

Here is the fiddle (I added some classes to display your menu element): http://jsfiddle.net/kost/4k0ebxnz/

```
.nav-menu-item-357 .main-menu-link.sf-with-ul:hover:after {
    border-top-color:#E81717;
}
```

Comment: You triangle is red in default state and you want to change it's color to red on hover. Change the deafult color ::after to black. Here is another fiddle using your updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/kost/guwLshue/ (I changed default state to black).

Comment: This is right answer. Check OP's colour code is all same, ```#E81717```. You can't change colour of hover, unless you using different colour code.

Comment: Actually it hovers to yellow from red somewhere still. It's original. I'm trying to make it hover to red. I basically don't want a hover, man I should hav been clear. I need it to remain red :(

Comment: @CodePitbull you should clarify your question then

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following

```
<span class="span">test</span>
```

to add an arrow on that span after test you would do something like the following in css:

```
span:after {
    content: '->'
}
```

now to change the color of the arrow on hovering you must do the following

```
span:hover:after {
    color:red;
}
```

working fiddle here

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/01u3fo8q/1/)

Comment: Can I not change the HTML? Any other way to make this work? 
This is from a WP PHP theme, I'm not sure which files this came from

Comment: why dont you access the styles.css of that particular theme in wordpress editor,find the elements that need to be changed and do the appropriate changes? i don't know how to change that using html and i don't seem to think that its possible.Read more here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css", another thing you can do is create a custom.css file and load that file in wordpress. note that the heirarchy for changes to overwrite default you should be loading your custom.css file last.