# Hover over an image inside html code

Tags: html, css, email, shopify

```
<img src="url" alt="a picture" style="width:42px;height:48px;background-color:#454141;">
```

I want to be able to change the  background color of an image when i hover over the image.
How can i do this built into the html code.
I have tried  `hover:background-color:green;`but this does not  work.

It's for shopify email notifications system , so i cant create a new style sheet(easily)

Note , the image is designed as clear as to be able to select any color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Answer (score 0):

An inline style attribute can only contain property declarations, that means you cannot use `:hover` this way.

You need to create a separate CSS file and write it as -

```
img:hover {
    /*Your code*/
}
```