# How to make an HTML anchor tag bolder on hover without css, only changing the inline style?

Tags: html, hover

I am trying to make the following anchor tags look bolder on hover, without using any external or embedded CSS file, can I make them look bolder by applying inline style?

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things"  target="_blank" ">Internet of things<br></a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_to_machine"  target="_blank">M2M<br></a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking"  target="_blank">Mesh Network<br></a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telemetry"  target="_blank">Telemetry<br></a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_sensor_network"  target="_blank">WSN</a>
```

Comment: Please indent code by four spaces to show it properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with inline CSS. You have to use normal `<style>` tag or a separate sheet:

```
a {
    font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I strongly recommend that you try to do it with CSS, but if you must do it with JS, here's a solution:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things" onmouseover="this.style.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="this.style.fontWeight='normal'" target="_blank" ">Internet of things<br></a>
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/72ehppr1/

Comment: Thank you so much,very helpful for a beginner like me.

Comment: Sure. Again, I recommend that you use the CSS way instead (updated the post)

Answer (score 0):

According to this, no:
[How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

But you can do it with javascript, using the `onmouseover` event