# How can I change HTML5 progress bar color inline?

Tags: css, html, webkit, progress-bar

I need to change the color of a progress bar based on some PHP values. I am not familiar with the WebKit technology, but as far as I understand it, it's the only way to change the progress bar color. So, I need to do something like this:

```
<progress style="progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: red; }" max="<?php echo $max; ?>" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"></progress>
```

Comment: We will need to see additional code that you have tried, what you provided seems partial.

Comment: <progress style="progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: #0063a6; }" max="<?php echo $max; ?>" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"></progress>

Comment: I dont have any other css related code for this...

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered before. See [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033182/5727498).

Just like `:hover` is part of the *selector*, `::-webkit-progress-value` is also part of the selector. Unfortunately the `style` attribute allows you to specify *rules* only.

Answer (score -1):

Change the bg color based in the value, something like the following will do the trick:

```
progress[value^="5"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

It applies the blue color to the bar for all the values that start with the number 5.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am still having problem implementing it.  Could you please specify what exactly I need to put into my html code and into my css.  Do I need to include any outside css files?  I am sorry I am so raw in this...

Comment: @sashalev you can ckeck this sample code, will help you a lot: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/Lukof63x/

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, this is exactly what i needed!