# change opacity on hover bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<button type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-lg btn-link" style="color: grey;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" style="font-size: xx-large"></i></button>
```

I added inline style to change the button style property. Now it won't change opacity when I hover my mouse pointer over it. Is there a way to specify that ? I am using twitter bootstrap 3.0

Comment: where is your other css?

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap. So I reference the CSS file on top my html page  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />`

Comment: Where is you closing tag? Make proper button first http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Comment: Ok I updated my question to reflect the entire tag closure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.btn-link:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

You need to add opacity to .btn-link so this will not effect all buttons in your website

Comment: no you can't, Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Answer (score 2):

I would make my own css class that uses :hover and then set the opacity property of the html element like so:

```
.btn-opacity:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.btn-opacity {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: I would make sure to have the filter for IE8 and earlier you want to make sure to keep browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding that feature in your CSS

```
button:hover{
  opacity: .5;
}
```

But this specifies that all buttons opacity will change to 50% when you hover and I'm not sure if that helps!

Comment: is there a way to do this inline ?

Answer (score 1):

Inline method
This will works for you..

```
<button onmouseover = "this.style.opacity = '0.5'" onmouseout = "this.style.opacity = '1'" type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-lg btn-link" style="color: grey;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" style="font-size: xx-large"></i>submit</button>
```