# How to give hover effect in inline html?

Tags: html, css

I want to give inline css for p tag in html inline,so what i need is something look likes this,

```
<p class="skill" style="hover {border-color:#20b920;}">Node.js</p>
```

Is there a way to give such thing in inline html,

Comment: Short answer : you can't,Long answer : bad practice                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to do it (in my opinion)

Use css with selector p.skill:hover.

For example:

```
p.skill:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Source https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

The way you want to do...
Use javascript

```
<p class="skill" onmouseover="this.style='background-color:#20b920;';" onmouseout="this.style='background-color:white';">Node.js</p>
```

Don't forget to change "white" to color of parent element background.

Comment: I don't need this,I need INLINE css

Comment: If i don't give inline css i have to add 10-12 separate different classes and different styles for them

Comment: You can use javascript for this

Comment: But this is VERY BAD IDEA to do it, because it will be very difficult to update.

Comment: Thanks javascript did the work