# How to automatically change the background color on onclick, using JQuery and JSON API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a list of users displayed in my HTML page. I want when you click username in the list automatically it should change the background color to user favorite color.

so far this is what I have got !.

```
var data =[{"id":987,"username":"jstephensre","active":false,"password":"8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10","first_name":"Johnny","last_name":"Stephens","last_login":"6/7/2016","email":"jstephensre@opensource.org","avatar":"https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117187617-3","color":"#6adf06","drugs":["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts","BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"8.65972","lng":"-75.12809"}},
{"id":988,"username":"dtorresrf","active":true,"password":"443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0","first_name":null,"last_name":"Torres","last_login":null,"email":"atorresrf@facebook.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#a04fce","drugs":["Cockroach, American","Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"9.86667","lng":"6.71667"}},
{"id":989,"username":"jsmithrg","active":false,"password":"4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad","first_name":null,"last_name":"Smith","last_login":null,"email":"tsmithrg@creativecommons.org","avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#3bff1e","drugs":["Yellow Pine","Meprobamate","GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-16.00528","lng":"-41.29722"}},
{"id":990,"username":"sroserh","active":false,"password":"ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":null,"last_login":"12/19/2015","email":"sromerorh@about.me","avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117541910-9","color":"#ac8603","drugs":["MORUS ALBA POLLEN","enema","Altipres-B"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"32.26616","lng":"35.00893"}},
{"id":991,"username":"sholmesri","active":false,"password":"11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543","first_name":"Susan","last_name":"Holmes","last_login":"1/28/2016","email":"sholmesri@mozilla.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"658583882-3","color":"#04da21","drugs":["Tempra","Estradiol Transdermal System"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-39.23686","lng":"-70.9197"}},
{"id":992,"username":"rhayesrj","active":true,"password":"beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259","first_name":"Rachel","last_name":"Hayes","last_login":"12/7/2015","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"291847889-X","color":null,"drugs":["BUDESONIDE","Doxorubicin Hydrochloride","Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-20.58333","lng":"48.53333"}},
{"id":993,"username":"jcampbellrk","active":false,"password":"9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537","first_name":"Joan","last_name":"Campbell","last_login":"8/29/2016","email":"jcampbellrk@bravesites.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"588841638-X","color":"#7c5963","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.6531","lng":"14.6968"}},
{"id":994,"username":"ejamesrl","active":false,"password":"55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"James","last_login":"1/14/2016","email":"ejamesrl@geocities.jp","avatar":null,"gender":["Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"026417147-0","color":"#ba1d5c","drugs":["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide","Ramipril"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"54.64043","lng":"32.87811"}},
{"id":995,"username":"krogersrm","active":true,"password":"c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130","first_name":"Kathleen","last_name":null,"last_login":"6/13/2016","email":"khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"636138809-3","color":"#1c858e","drugs":["Tramadol Hydrochloride","iBlanc Restora-Bright"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"12.71402","lng":"121.51242"}},
{"id":996,"username":"sperkinsrn","active":false,"password":"c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Perkins","last_login":"8/31/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"561211079-0","color":null,"drugs":["Caduet"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"43.30472","lng":"124.32778"}},
{"id":997,"username":"jlanero","active":false,"password":"0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5","first_name":"Jack","last_name":"Lane","last_login":"3/20/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"819102101-3","color":null,"drugs":["RIFAMPIN"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.8796","lng":"4.5059"}},
{"id":998,"username":"wroserp","active":true,"password":"626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9","first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Rose","last_login":"10/16/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"108540866-3","color":null,"drugs":["OXYGEN","Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.58167","lng":"83.76917"}},
{"id":999,"username":"sphillipsrq","active":false,"password":"de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439","first_name":"Stephanie","last_name":"Phillips","last_login":"11/24/2016","email":"sphillipsrq@wikia.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"721916787-3","color":"#9eee74","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.0016","lng":"21.71474"}},
{"id":1000,"username":"phicksrr","active":false,"password":"2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb","first_name":"Phyllis","last_name":"Hicks","last_login":"2/14/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"268196481-4","color":null,"drugs":["Ibuprofen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-6.22625","lng":"106.0253"}}];



 var output = '<ul>';


 $.each(data, function(key, val) {

     if(val['active'] == true)
      {
         output += '<li><a class="new_href" href="'+val.id+'">'+ val.first_name + " " + val.last_name + " " + val.username +'</a></li>';

      }
 });
```

can anyone please provide a simple solution to accomplish this?

NOTE: each user has a key named favorites containing books or color

Comment: Have you tried _anything_....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `data-color` to your `a` element so you can reuse this data

```js
var data =[{"id":987,"username":"jstephensre","active":false,"password":"8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10","first_name":"Johnny","last_name":"Stephens","last_login":"6/7/2016","email":"jstephensre@opensource.org","avatar":"https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117187617-3","color":"#6adf06","drugs":["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts","BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"8.65972","lng":"-75.12809"}},
{"id":988,"username":"dtorresrf","active":true,"password":"443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0","first_name":null,"last_name":"Torres","last_login":null,"email":"atorresrf@facebook.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#a04fce","drugs":["Cockroach, American","Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"9.86667","lng":"6.71667"}},
{"id":989,"username":"jsmithrg","active":false,"password":"4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad","first_name":null,"last_name":"Smith","last_login":null,"email":"tsmithrg@creativecommons.org","avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#3bff1e","drugs":["Yellow Pine","Meprobamate","GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-16.00528","lng":"-41.29722"}},
{"id":990,"username":"sroserh","active":false,"password":"ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":null,"last_login":"12/19/2015","email":"sromerorh@about.me","avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117541910-9","color":"#ac8603","drugs":["MORUS ALBA POLLEN","enema","Altipres-B"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"32.26616","lng":"35.00893"}},
{"id":991,"username":"sholmesri","active":false,"password":"11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543","first_name":"Susan","last_name":"Holmes","last_login":"1/28/2016","email":"sholmesri@mozilla.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"658583882-3","color":"#04da21","drugs":["Tempra","Estradiol Transdermal System"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-39.23686","lng":"-70.9197"}},
{"id":992,"username":"rhayesrj","active":true,"password":"beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259","first_name":"Rachel","last_name":"Hayes","last_login":"12/7/2015","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"291847889-X","color":null,"drugs":["BUDESONIDE","Doxorubicin Hydrochloride","Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-20.58333","lng":"48.53333"}},
{"id":993,"username":"jcampbellrk","active":false,"password":"9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537","first_name":"Joan","last_name":"Campbell","last_login":"8/29/2016","email":"jcampbellrk@bravesites.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"588841638-X","color":"#7c5963","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.6531","lng":"14.6968"}},
{"id":994,"username":"ejamesrl","active":false,"password":"55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"James","last_login":"1/14/2016","email":"ejamesrl@geocities.jp","avatar":null,"gender":["Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"026417147-0","color":"#ba1d5c","drugs":["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide","Ramipril"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"54.64043","lng":"32.87811"}},
{"id":995,"username":"krogersrm","active":true,"password":"c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130","first_name":"Kathleen","last_name":null,"last_login":"6/13/2016","email":"khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"636138809-3","color":"#1c858e","drugs":["Tramadol Hydrochloride","iBlanc Restora-Bright"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"12.71402","lng":"121.51242"}},
{"id":996,"username":"sperkinsrn","active":false,"password":"c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Perkins","last_login":"8/31/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"561211079-0","color":null,"drugs":["Caduet"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"43.30472","lng":"124.32778"}},
{"id":997,"username":"jlanero","active":false,"password":"0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5","first_name":"Jack","last_name":"Lane","last_login":"3/20/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"819102101-3","color":null,"drugs":["RIFAMPIN"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.8796","lng":"4.5059"}},
{"id":998,"username":"wroserp","active":true,"password":"626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9","first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Rose","last_login":"10/16/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"108540866-3","color":null,"drugs":["OXYGEN","Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.58167","lng":"83.76917"}},
{"id":999,"username":"sphillipsrq","active":false,"password":"de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439","first_name":"Stephanie","last_name":"Phillips","last_login":"11/24/2016","email":"sphillipsrq@wikia.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"721916787-3","color":"#9eee74","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.0016","lng":"21.71474"}},
{"id":1000,"username":"phicksrr","active":false,"password":"2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb","first_name":"Phyllis","last_name":"Hicks","last_login":"2/14/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"268196481-4","color":null,"drugs":["Ibuprofen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-6.22625","lng":"106.0253"}}];


 var output = '<ul>';
 
 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
  if(val.active === true) {
    output += '<li><a class="new_href" href="' + val.id + '" data-color="' + val.favorites.color + '">' + val.first_name + " " + val.last_name + " " + val.username + '</a></li>';
  }
});

$('body').append(output)

$('li>a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('color'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is good bro and works ok but I want the page background to change color when u click username in the list according to user favorites color

Comment: if you want to change page background replace `$(this).css` with `$('body').css`

Comment: Thank you works perfectly. I have another question hope u can help , using the same JSON API if u click the username I want to display user info eg name, username, last name, CITY(using coordinates) using google API, when u click the username the window should pop up and display that info with static map together, is it possible to achieve that? if so can you provide some tutorial or script to do that?

Comment: accept this answer, then create new question because that different problem, so we can help you.

Comment: The new Thread is here : [Inline Link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450720/how-to-display-city-name-using-coordinates-with-google-map-api-using-jquery-and?noredirect=1#comment77862698_45450720

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the *background-color* to the favorite color:

```
var output="";
 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
   if(val['active'] == true){
     output +=`
      <li onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor='${val.favorites.color}'">
       <a class="new_href" href="${val.id}">
          ${val.first_name} ${val.last_name} ${val.username}
        </a>
      </li>`;
  }
 });

$(document.body).html(ouput);
```

The upper code uses ES6 string literals. I think theyre more beautiful then the string concatenation, however thats up to you.

Answer based on [the second answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

[In action!](http://jsbin.com/bozuxerori/edit?output)

Comment: @bonge labwana shure

Comment: Jonas what do u mean_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

Here is working demo: https://output.jsbin.com/tayacik

https://jsbin.com/tayacik/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var data = [{"id":987,"username":"jstephensre","active":false,"password":"8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10","first_name":"Johnny","last_name":"Stephens","last_login":"6/7/2016","email":"jstephensre@opensource.org","avatar":"https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117187617-3","color":"#6adf06","drugs":["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts","BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"8.65972","lng":"-75.12809"}},
{"id":988,"username":"dtorresrf","active":true,"password":"443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0","first_name":null,"last_name":"Torres","last_login":null,"email":"atorresrf@facebook.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#a04fce","drugs":["Cockroach, American","Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"9.86667","lng":"6.71667"}},
{"id":989,"username":"jsmithrg","active":false,"password":"4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad","first_name":null,"last_name":"Smith","last_login":null,"email":"tsmithrg@creativecommons.org","avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#3bff1e","drugs":["Yellow Pine","Meprobamate","GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-16.00528","lng":"-41.29722"}},
{"id":990,"username":"sroserh","active":false,"password":"ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":null,"last_login":"12/19/2015","email":"sromerorh@about.me","avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117541910-9","color":"#ac8603","drugs":["MORUS ALBA POLLEN","enema","Altipres-B"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"32.26616","lng":"35.00893"}},
{"id":991,"username":"sholmesri","active":false,"password":"11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543","first_name":"Susan","last_name":"Holmes","last_login":"1/28/2016","email":"sholmesri@mozilla.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"658583882-3","color":"#04da21","drugs":["Tempra","Estradiol Transdermal System"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-39.23686","lng":"-70.9197"}},
{"id":992,"username":"rhayesrj","active":true,"password":"beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259","first_name":"Rachel","last_name":"Hayes","last_login":"12/7/2015","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"291847889-X","color":null,"drugs":["BUDESONIDE","Doxorubicin Hydrochloride","Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-20.58333","lng":"48.53333"}},
{"id":993,"username":"jcampbellrk","active":false,"password":"9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537","first_name":"Joan","last_name":"Campbell","last_login":"8/29/2016","email":"jcampbellrk@bravesites.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"588841638-X","color":"#7c5963","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.6531","lng":"14.6968"}},
{"id":994,"username":"ejamesrl","active":false,"password":"55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"James","last_login":"1/14/2016","email":"ejamesrl@geocities.jp","avatar":null,"gender":["Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"026417147-0","color":"#ba1d5c","drugs":["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide","Ramipril"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"54.64043","lng":"32.87811"}},
{"id":995,"username":"krogersrm","active":true,"password":"c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130","first_name":"Kathleen","last_name":null,"last_login":"6/13/2016","email":"khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"636138809-3","color":"#1c858e","drugs":["Tramadol Hydrochloride","iBlanc Restora-Bright"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"12.71402","lng":"121.51242"}},
{"id":996,"username":"sperkinsrn","active":false,"password":"c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Perkins","last_login":"8/31/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"561211079-0","color":null,"drugs":["Caduet"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"43.30472","lng":"124.32778"}},
{"id":997,"username":"jlanero","active":false,"password":"0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5","first_name":"Jack","last_name":"Lane","last_login":"3/20/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"819102101-3","color":null,"drugs":["RIFAMPIN"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.8796","lng":"4.5059"}},
{"id":998,"username":"wroserp","active":true,"password":"626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9","first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Rose","last_login":"10/16/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"108540866-3","color":null,"drugs":["OXYGEN","Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.58167","lng":"83.76917"}},
{"id":999,"username":"sphillipsrq","active":false,"password":"de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439","first_name":"Stephanie","last_name":"Phillips","last_login":"11/24/2016","email":"sphillipsrq@wikia.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"721916787-3","color":"#9eee74","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.0016","lng":"21.71474"}},
{"id":1000,"username":"phicksrr","active":false,"password":"2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb","first_name":"Phyllis","last_name":"Hicks","last_login":"2/14/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"268196481-4","color":null,"drugs":["Ibuprofen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-6.22625","lng":"106.0253"}}];

 var output = '<ul>';
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
   if(data[i].active == true)
    {
        output += '<li style="background-color:'+ data[i].favorites.color +'"><a class="new_href" href="'+data[i].id+'">'+ data[i].first_name + " " + data[i].last_name + " " + data[i].username +'</a></li>';

    }
  });
output += '</ul>';

  $("#results").html(output);

 });
```

Comment: hii I want the whole page to change the background color according to user favourite color not only one line , when u cick username in  the list the background color changes according to user favourite color

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var data = [{ "id": 987, "username": "jstephensre", "active": false, "password": "8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10", "first_name": "Johnny", "last_name": "Stephens", "last_login": "6/7/2016", "email": "jstephensre@opensource.org", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "117187617-3", "color": "#6adf06", "drugs": ["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts", "BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "8.65972", "lng": "-75.12809" } },
{ "id": 988, "username": "dtorresrf", "active": true, "password": "443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0", "first_name": null, "last_name": "Torres", "last_login": null, "email": "atorresrf@facebook.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Female", "Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": null, "color": "#a04fce", "drugs": ["Cockroach, American", "Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "9.86667", "lng": "6.71667" } },
{ "id": 989, "username": "jsmithrg", "active": false, "password": "4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad", "first_name": null, "last_name": "Smith", "last_login": null, "email": "tsmithrg@creativecommons.org", "avatar": null, "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": null, "color": "#3bff1e", "drugs": ["Yellow Pine", "Meprobamate", "GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-16.00528", "lng": "-41.29722" } },
{ "id": 990, "username": "sroserh", "active": false, "password": "ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3", "first_name": "Sarah", "last_name": null, "last_login": "12/19/2015", "email": "sromerorh@about.me", "avatar": null, "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "117541910-9", "color": "#ac8603", "drugs": ["MORUS ALBA POLLEN", "enema", "Altipres-B"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "32.26616", "lng": "35.00893" } },
{ "id": 991, "username": "sholmesri", "active": false, "password": "11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543", "first_name": "Susan", "last_name": "Holmes", "last_login": "1/28/2016", "email": "sholmesri@mozilla.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male", "Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "658583882-3", "color": "#04da21", "drugs": ["Tempra", "Estradiol Transdermal System"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-39.23686", "lng": "-70.9197" } },
{ "id": 992, "username": "rhayesrj", "active": true, "password": "beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259", "first_name": "Rachel", "last_name": "Hayes", "last_login": "12/7/2015", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "291847889-X", "color": null, "drugs": ["BUDESONIDE", "Doxorubicin Hydrochloride", "Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-20.58333", "lng": "48.53333" } },
{ "id": 993, "username": "jcampbellrk", "active": false, "password": "9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537", "first_name": "Joan", "last_name": "Campbell", "last_login": "8/29/2016", "email": "jcampbellrk@bravesites.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "588841638-X", "color": "#7c5963", "drugs": [] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "57.6531", "lng": "14.6968" } },
{ "id": 994, "username": "ejamesrl", "active": false, "password": "55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab", "first_name": "Elizabeth", "last_name": "James", "last_login": "1/14/2016", "email": "ejamesrl@geocities.jp", "avatar": null, "gender": ["Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "026417147-0", "color": "#ba1d5c", "drugs": ["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide", "Ramipril"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "54.64043", "lng": "32.87811" } },
{ "id": 995, "username": "krogersrm", "active": true, "password": "c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130", "first_name": "Kathleen", "last_name": null, "last_login": "6/13/2016", "email": "khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "636138809-3", "color": "#1c858e", "drugs": ["Tramadol Hydrochloride", "iBlanc Restora-Bright"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "12.71402", "lng": "121.51242" } },
{ "id": 996, "username": "sperkinsrn", "active": false, "password": "c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8", "first_name": "Sarah", "last_name": "Perkins", "last_login": "8/31/2016", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male", "Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "561211079-0", "color": null, "drugs": ["Caduet"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "43.30472", "lng": "124.32778" } },
{ "id": 997, "username": "jlanero", "active": false, "password": "0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5", "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "Lane", "last_login": "3/20/2016", "email": null, "avatar": null, "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "819102101-3", "color": null, "drugs": ["RIFAMPIN"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "51.8796", "lng": "4.5059" } },
{ "id": 998, "username": "wroserp", "active": true, "password": "626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9", "first_name": "Willie", "last_name": "Rose", "last_login": "10/16/2016", "email": null, "avatar": null, "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "108540866-3", "color": null, "drugs": ["OXYGEN", "Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "57.58167", "lng": "83.76917" } },
{ "id": 999, "username": "sphillipsrq", "active": false, "password": "de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439", "first_name": "Stephanie", "last_name": "Phillips", "last_login": "11/24/2016", "email": "sphillipsrq@wikia.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "721916787-3", "color": "#9eee74", "drugs": [] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "51.0016", "lng": "21.71474" } },
{ "id": 1000, "username": "phicksrr", "active": false, "password": "2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb", "first_name": "Phyllis", "last_name": "Hicks", "last_login": "2/14/2016", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Female", "Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "268196481-4", "color": null, "drugs": ["Ibuprofen"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-6.22625", "lng": "106.0253" } }];


var username = '';

$(function () {

   
    var html = '';
    $.each(data,function(){
      html+='<a>'+this.username+'</a><br>';
    });
    
    $('div').append(html)
    
    $('a').on('click',function(){
      username= $(this).text();   
       var d = data.filter(filterByUsername)
       var val = d[0];
       var color = val.favorites.color;
       if(color)
       {
          $(this).css('color','#fff');
          $(this).css('background-color',color);
        }
    });
});


function filterByUsername(item) {

    if (item.username == username) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another one nice. If I want the whole page to change its background color according to user favorite color  if I click the user name in the list what should I change in that code of yours? am learning though hope u don't mind.

Comment: updated check it again. 

"$('body').css('color',color);

Comment: I see but still, it changes the color of all users, not the background color of the page when I click user with favorite color, I tested it in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/8erwrha2/

Comment: Thanks, bro , it works too but the other guy had the best short and clear answer to that so I accepted his answer, hope u don't mind, I have new thread can you check it out? [Inline Link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450720/how-to-display-city-name-using-coordinates-with-google-map-api-using-jquery-and?noredirect=1#comment77862698_45450720

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet to change the `body` background based on the user color:

Actual code:

```
$(function() {
  var username = '';
  var html = '';
  $.each(data, function() {
    html += '<a data-color="' + this.favorites.color + '">' + this.username + '</a><br>';
  });

  $('div').append(html);
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css('background', $(this).data('color'));
  });
});
```

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 987,
    "username": "jstephensre",
    "active": false,
    "password": "8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10",
    "first_name": "Johnny",
    "last_name": "Stephens",
    "last_login": "6/7/2016",
    "email": "jstephensre@opensource.org",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "117187617-3",
      "color": "#6adf06",
      "drugs": ["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts", "BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "8.65972",
      "lng": "-75.12809"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 988,
    "username": "dtorresrf",
    "active": true,
    "password": "443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": "Torres",
    "last_login": null,
    "email": "atorresrf@facebook.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Female", "Female"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": null,
      "color": "#a04fce",
      "drugs": ["Cockroach, American", "Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "9.86667",
      "lng": "6.71667"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 989,
    "username": "jsmithrg",
    "active": false,
    "password": "4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "last_login": null,
    "email": "tsmithrg@creativecommons.org",
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": null,
      "color": "#3bff1e",
      "drugs": ["Yellow Pine", "Meprobamate", "GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-16.00528",
      "lng": "-41.29722"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 990,
    "username": "sroserh",
    "active": false,
    "password": "ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3",
    "first_name": "Sarah",
    "last_name": null,
    "last_login": "12/19/2015",
    "email": "sromerorh@about.me",
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "117541910-9",
      "color": "#ac8603",
      "drugs": ["MORUS ALBA POLLEN", "enema", "Altipres-B"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "32.26616",
      "lng": "35.00893"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 991,
    "username": "sholmesri",
    "active": false,
    "password": "11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543",
    "first_name": "Susan",
    "last_name": "Holmes",
    "last_login": "1/28/2016",
    "email": "sholmesri@mozilla.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male", "Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "658583882-3",
      "color": "#04da21",
      "drugs": ["Tempra", "Estradiol Transdermal System"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-39.23686",
      "lng": "-70.9197"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 992,
    "username": "rhayesrj",
    "active": true,
    "password": "beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259",
    "first_name": "Rachel",
    "last_name": "Hayes",
    "last_login": "12/7/2015",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "291847889-X",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["BUDESONIDE", "Doxorubicin Hydrochloride", "Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-20.58333",
      "lng": "48.53333"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 993,
    "username": "jcampbellrk",
    "active": false,
    "password": "9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537",
    "first_name": "Joan",
    "last_name": "Campbell",
    "last_login": "8/29/2016",
    "email": "jcampbellrk@bravesites.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "588841638-X",
      "color": "#7c5963",
      "drugs": []
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "57.6531",
      "lng": "14.6968"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 994,
    "username": "ejamesrl",
    "active": false,
    "password": "55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab",
    "first_name": "Elizabeth",
    "last_name": "James",
    "last_login": "1/14/2016",
    "email": "ejamesrl@geocities.jp",
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": ["Female"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "026417147-0",
      "color": "#ba1d5c",
      "drugs": ["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide", "Ramipril"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "54.64043",
      "lng": "32.87811"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 995,
    "username": "krogersrm",
    "active": true,
    "password": "c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130",
    "first_name": "Kathleen",
    "last_name": null,
    "last_login": "6/13/2016",
    "email": "khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "636138809-3",
      "color": "#1c858e",
      "drugs": ["Tramadol Hydrochloride", "iBlanc Restora-Bright"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "12.71402",
      "lng": "121.51242"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 996,
    "username": "sperkinsrn",
    "active": false,
    "password": "c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8",
    "first_name": "Sarah",
    "last_name": "Perkins",
    "last_login": "8/31/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male", "Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "561211079-0",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["Caduet"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "43.30472",
      "lng": "124.32778"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 997,
    "username": "jlanero",
    "active": false,
    "password": "0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5",
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "last_name": "Lane",
    "last_login": "3/20/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "819102101-3",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["RIFAMPIN"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "51.8796",
      "lng": "4.5059"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 998,
    "username": "wroserp",
    "active": true,
    "password": "626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9",
    "first_name": "Willie",
    "last_name": "Rose",
    "last_login": "10/16/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "108540866-3",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["OXYGEN", "Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "57.58167",
      "lng": "83.76917"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 999,
    "username": "sphillipsrq",
    "active": false,
    "password": "de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439",
    "first_name": "Stephanie",
    "last_name": "Phillips",
    "last_login": "11/24/2016",
    "email": "sphillipsrq@wikia.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "721916787-3",
      "color": "#9eee74",
      "drugs": []
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "51.0016",
      "lng": "21.71474"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1000,
    "username": "phicksrr",
    "active": false,
    "password": "2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb",
    "first_name": "Phyllis",
    "last_name": "Hicks",
    "last_login": "2/14/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Female", "Female"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "268196481-4",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["Ibuprofen"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-6.22625",
      "lng": "106.0253"
    }
  }
];


$(function() {
  var username = '';
  var html = '';
  $.each(data, function() {
    html += '<a data-color="' + this.favorites.color + '">' + this.username + '</a><br>';
  });

  $('div').append(html);
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css('background', $(this).data('color'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Copying another users answer is not very nice :/

Comment: @Jonasw - Sorry? I edited it completely and is way smaller.

Comment: im referring to your original answer... Now its fine