# How to display city name using coordinates with google map API using Jquery and Json API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, google-maps

I want to display user info containing (name, username, city name, etc), if u click the username I want to display user info eg name, username, last name, CITY(using coordinates) using google API, when u click the username the window should pop up and display that info with static map together,

is it possible to achieve that? if so can you provide some tutorial or script to do that?

Note: I am a newbie I dont know even where to start with this problem,

Here is  what I have done so far :

```
var data = [{ "id": 987, "username": "jstephensre", "active": false, "password": "8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10", "first_name": "Johnny", "last_name": "Stephens", "last_login": "6/7/2016", "email": "jstephensre@opensource.org", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "117187617-3", "color": "#6adf06", "drugs": ["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts", "BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "8.65972", "lng": "-75.12809" } },
{ "id": 988, "username": "dtorresrf", "active": true, "password": "443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0", "first_name": null, "last_name": "Torres", "last_login": null, "email": "atorresrf@facebook.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Female", "Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": null, "color": "#a04fce", "drugs": ["Cockroach, American", "Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "9.86667", "lng": "6.71667" } },
{ "id": 989, "username": "jsmithrg", "active": false, "password": "4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad", "first_name": null, "last_name": "Smith", "last_login": null, "email": "tsmithrg@creativecommons.org", "avatar": null, "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": null, "color": "#3bff1e", "drugs": ["Yellow Pine", "Meprobamate", "GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-16.00528", "lng": "-41.29722" } },
{ "id": 990, "username": "sroserh", "active": false, "password": "ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3", "first_name": "Sarah", "last_name": null, "last_login": "12/19/2015", "email": "sromerorh@about.me", "avatar": null, "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "117541910-9", "color": "#ac8603", "drugs": ["MORUS ALBA POLLEN", "enema", "Altipres-B"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "32.26616", "lng": "35.00893" } },
{ "id": 991, "username": "sholmesri", "active": false, "password": "11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543", "first_name": "Susan", "last_name": "Holmes", "last_login": "1/28/2016", "email": "sholmesri@mozilla.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male", "Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "658583882-3", "color": "#04da21", "drugs": ["Tempra", "Estradiol Transdermal System"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-39.23686", "lng": "-70.9197" } },
{ "id": 992, "username": "rhayesrj", "active": true, "password": "beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259", "first_name": "Rachel", "last_name": "Hayes", "last_login": "12/7/2015", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "291847889-X", "color": null, "drugs": ["BUDESONIDE", "Doxorubicin Hydrochloride", "Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-20.58333", "lng": "48.53333" } },
{ "id": 993, "username": "jcampbellrk", "active": false, "password": "9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537", "first_name": "Joan", "last_name": "Campbell", "last_login": "8/29/2016", "email": "jcampbellrk@bravesites.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "588841638-X", "color": "#7c5963", "drugs": [] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "57.6531", "lng": "14.6968" } },
{ "id": 994, "username": "ejamesrl", "active": false, "password": "55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab", "first_name": "Elizabeth", "last_name": "James", "last_login": "1/14/2016", "email": "ejamesrl@geocities.jp", "avatar": null, "gender": ["Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "026417147-0", "color": "#ba1d5c", "drugs": ["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide", "Ramipril"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "54.64043", "lng": "32.87811" } },
{ "id": 995, "username": "krogersrm", "active": true, "password": "c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130", "first_name": "Kathleen", "last_name": null, "last_login": "6/13/2016", "email": "khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "636138809-3", "color": "#1c858e", "drugs": ["Tramadol Hydrochloride", "iBlanc Restora-Bright"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "12.71402", "lng": "121.51242" } },
{ "id": 996, "username": "sperkinsrn", "active": false, "password": "c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8", "first_name": "Sarah", "last_name": "Perkins", "last_login": "8/31/2016", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male", "Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "561211079-0", "color": null, "drugs": ["Caduet"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "43.30472", "lng": "124.32778" } },
{ "id": 997, "username": "jlanero", "active": false, "password": "0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5", "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "Lane", "last_login": "3/20/2016", "email": null, "avatar": null, "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "819102101-3", "color": null, "drugs": ["RIFAMPIN"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "51.8796", "lng": "4.5059" } },
{ "id": 998, "username": "wroserp", "active": true, "password": "626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9", "first_name": "Willie", "last_name": "Rose", "last_login": "10/16/2016", "email": null, "avatar": null, "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "108540866-3", "color": null, "drugs": ["OXYGEN", "Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "57.58167", "lng": "83.76917" } },
{ "id": 999, "username": "sphillipsrq", "active": false, "password": "de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439", "first_name": "Stephanie", "last_name": "Phillips", "last_login": "11/24/2016", "email": "sphillipsrq@wikia.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "721916787-3", "color": "#9eee74", "drugs": [] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "51.0016", "lng": "21.71474" } },
{ "id": 1000, "username": "phicksrr", "active": false, "password": "2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb", "first_name": "Phyllis", "last_name": "Hicks", "last_login": "2/14/2016", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Female", "Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "268196481-4", "color": null, "drugs": ["Ibuprofen"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-6.22625", "lng": "106.0253" } }];



        var output = '<ul>';


        $.each(data, function(key, val) {

            //check the user if is active then display the active users
              if(val['active'] == true)
              {
            output += '<li>'<a  href=  + val.avatar + " " + val.first_name + " " + val.last_name + " " + val.coordinates " " + val.username +'</a></li>';





        }


                });
```

Comment: You said you're new. I give you something to read for this task you want to achieve: [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) documentation.

Comment: thanks bror I will try my best

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code. I have made some code for you to start.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 987,
    "username": "jstephensre",
    "active": false,
    "password": "8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10",
    "first_name": "Johnny",
    "last_name": "Stephens",
    "last_login": "6/7/2016",
    "email": "jstephensre@opensource.org",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "117187617-3",
      "color": "#6adf06",
      "drugs": ["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts", "BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "8.65972",
      "lng": "-75.12809"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 988,
    "username": "dtorresrf",
    "active": true,
    "password": "443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": "Torres",
    "last_login": null,
    "email": "atorresrf@facebook.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Female", "Female"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": null,
      "color": "#a04fce",
      "drugs": ["Cockroach, American", "Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "9.86667",
      "lng": "6.71667"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 989,
    "username": "jsmithrg",
    "active": false,
    "password": "4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "last_login": null,
    "email": "tsmithrg@creativecommons.org",
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": null,
      "color": "#3bff1e",
      "drugs": ["Yellow Pine", "Meprobamate", "GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-16.00528",
      "lng": "-41.29722"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 990,
    "username": "sroserh",
    "active": false,
    "password": "ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3",
    "first_name": "Sarah",
    "last_name": null,
    "last_login": "12/19/2015",
    "email": "sromerorh@about.me",
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "117541910-9",
      "color": "#ac8603",
      "drugs": ["MORUS ALBA POLLEN", "enema", "Altipres-B"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "32.26616",
      "lng": "35.00893"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 991,
    "username": "sholmesri",
    "active": false,
    "password": "11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543",
    "first_name": "Susan",
    "last_name": "Holmes",
    "last_login": "1/28/2016",
    "email": "sholmesri@mozilla.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male", "Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "658583882-3",
      "color": "#04da21",
      "drugs": ["Tempra", "Estradiol Transdermal System"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-39.23686",
      "lng": "-70.9197"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 992,
    "username": "rhayesrj",
    "active": true,
    "password": "beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259",
    "first_name": "Rachel",
    "last_name": "Hayes",
    "last_login": "12/7/2015",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "291847889-X",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["BUDESONIDE", "Doxorubicin Hydrochloride", "Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-20.58333",
      "lng": "48.53333"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 993,
    "username": "jcampbellrk",
    "active": false,
    "password": "9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537",
    "first_name": "Joan",
    "last_name": "Campbell",
    "last_login": "8/29/2016",
    "email": "jcampbellrk@bravesites.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "588841638-X",
      "color": "#7c5963",
      "drugs": []
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "57.6531",
      "lng": "14.6968"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 994,
    "username": "ejamesrl",
    "active": false,
    "password": "55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab",
    "first_name": "Elizabeth",
    "last_name": "James",
    "last_login": "1/14/2016",
    "email": "ejamesrl@geocities.jp",
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": ["Female"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "026417147-0",
      "color": "#ba1d5c",
      "drugs": ["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide", "Ramipril"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "54.64043",
      "lng": "32.87811"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 995,
    "username": "krogersrm",
    "active": true,
    "password": "c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130",
    "first_name": "Kathleen",
    "last_name": null,
    "last_login": "6/13/2016",
    "email": "khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "636138809-3",
      "color": "#1c858e",
      "drugs": ["Tramadol Hydrochloride", "iBlanc Restora-Bright"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "12.71402",
      "lng": "121.51242"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 996,
    "username": "sperkinsrn",
    "active": false,
    "password": "c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8",
    "first_name": "Sarah",
    "last_name": "Perkins",
    "last_login": "8/31/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Male", "Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "561211079-0",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["Caduet"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "43.30472",
      "lng": "124.32778"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 997,
    "username": "jlanero",
    "active": false,
    "password": "0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5",
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "last_name": "Lane",
    "last_login": "3/20/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "819102101-3",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["RIFAMPIN"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "51.8796",
      "lng": "4.5059"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 998,
    "username": "wroserp",
    "active": true,
    "password": "626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9",
    "first_name": "Willie",
    "last_name": "Rose",
    "last_login": "10/16/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": null,
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "108540866-3",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["OXYGEN", "Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "57.58167",
      "lng": "83.76917"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 999,
    "username": "sphillipsrq",
    "active": false,
    "password": "de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439",
    "first_name": "Stephanie",
    "last_name": "Phillips",
    "last_login": "11/24/2016",
    "email": "sphillipsrq@wikia.com",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": [],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "721916787-3",
      "color": "#9eee74",
      "drugs": []
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "51.0016",
      "lng": "21.71474"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1000,
    "username": "phicksrr",
    "active": false,
    "password": "2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb",
    "first_name": "Phyllis",
    "last_name": "Hicks",
    "last_login": "2/14/2016",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1",
    "gender": ["Female", "Female"],
    "favorites": {
      "book-isbn": "268196481-4",
      "color": null,
      "drugs": ["Ibuprofen"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": "-6.22625",
      "lng": "106.0253"
    }
  }
];

var output = '<ul>';
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    //check the user if is active then display the active users
    if (val['active'] == true) {
      output += "<li><a href='#' onclick='getAddress(\"" + val.username + "\"," + val.coordinates.lat + "," + val.coordinates.lng + ")'>First Name: " + val.first_name + ",Last Name: " + val.last_name + ", Username: " + val.username + ",Lat: " + val.coordinates.lat + ",Lng: " + val.coordinates.lng + "</a></li>";
    }
  });
  $("#userList").html(output);
});

function getAddress(username, latitude, longitude) {
  var lat = latitude; //pass latitude value..
  var lng = longitude; //pass longitude value..
  $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=true", function(json) {
    //result contains json
    var address = json.results[0].formatted_address;

    $("#userDetails").html("<b>UserName:</b> " + username + "<br/><b>Address: </b>" + address);
  });
}
```

```css
#userList {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#userDetails {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding:5px;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userList">
</div>
<br/>
<div id="userDetails">
</div>
```

Comment: hii, I tried it displays nothing in my html can you please show it in jsfiddle ,? hope u dont mind , thank you though for help

Comment: Hi @BongeLaBwana. I have updated the answer, added full-code. Please check

Comment: displays username and coordinates not the city!

Comment: please click on that and check. while clicking on that link it will display details including city inside the div #userDetails. You can modify that to while clicking on a href show modal dialog that shows city

Comment: javascript function getAddress can be used to get city details. please check that code and try