# vuejs2 dynamic inline css for hover

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2

I have the following inline style that shows dynamic colors.

```
<router-link  :style="{ 'color': primaryColor }">Yay</router-link>
```

It works great, however, on hover, I'd like to show a different dynamic color. I looked in the documentation and didn't see anything about hover with inline style.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. This is not a limitation of Vue, but of browsers. Pseudo-selectors are not honored in inline style. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033166/8487308).