# What is the best way to write a:hover in inline CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know JavaScript will help. But there is no way to write such hover tags?

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Please show us some code that you tried. What are the actual results and what are the expected results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Comment: This is not related to php. but php is related to html. @ kerbholz

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean but it shouldn't be too different from this. Here I use the `onmouseover` attribute to achieve your description.

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="alert('Hello world')">This is a link</a>
```

You can then replace the `alert()` with a custom function in js to do what you want.