# Change Button Font Color on Hover With "Hover color" declared on each button tag not in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's not a duplicate question - I don't want to simply change the font color in CSS.

My Issue:

I have products with colors. Blue, Red, Green, Yellow, Purple - any kind of color.

I have a box with the same color -

And Inside this box I have a button "BUY"

I can create this button dynamic - with the same color  of the box.

If the box is blue - the button is blue with white border and white font color.

If the box is red - the button is red with white border and white font color.

the CSS (Inverse Button):

```
.btn-inv {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background-color: transparent;   
    border: 1px #ffffff solid;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

But in hover

```
.btn-inv:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
```

The button goes to white - and the font color to black.

THE ISSUE: I NEED THE FONT COLOR IN THE SAME COLOR OF THE BOX - if the box is blue, the font color is blue.

Of Course - If I change the CSS - I can do this.

But I need a dynamic way to do this - because I cannot create ALL buttons colors..

something using "style":

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-inv btn-lg" style=".HOVER: color: #4a62ab">BUY</a>
```

or anyother ideia with the color inside the  tag. because with this I can simply send the correct color information and create the button dynamically.

If I have 80 colors - I can use the same CSS for ALL - and just send the correct via ASP to dynamically complete the button.

and I don't need to create 80 CSS Buttons just because of this.

Comment: well, i'm not saying this is a duplicate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css) could help to narrow down the options you have.

Comment: hi @Aᴍɪʀ - yes, I try this too.. but all solutions are in JS. temani-afif give us a better solution - in CSS. tks a lot too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider CSS variables like this:

```css
a.btn {
 padding:0 10px;
 color:#000;
 border:1px solid;
}
a.btn:hover {
  color:var(--h, yellow);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-inv btn-lg" style="--h: #4a62ab">BUY</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-inv btn-lg" style="--h: red">BUY</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-inv btn-lg" style="--h: green">BUY</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-inv btn-lg" style="--h: #4a00fb">BUY</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-inv btn-lg">BUY</a> <!-- this one will get the default color (yellow) -->
```

Comment: Hi @temani-afif - GREAT!!!!!! I LOVE YOU!! :D - really! tks a lot! I tried many solutions and none works. You bring to me a great solution! tks a lot!!  tested and Accepted!

Comment: this is genius!