# Animation Button with plotly R - customize "hover" color

Tags: css, animation, button, r-plotly

I'd like to change the background color of the button when hovering over it - so eg. if not hovering over the button it should be blue and if hovering it should change to red.

What I tried: `animation_button(color = "red)` and (based on the options for *animation_slider*) `animation_button(activebgcolor = "red")`. Both didn't work - Moreover, I searched for the css options but couldn't find it either. Do you have an idea how to access the buttons 'hover' color and maybe also the 'hover' font color? Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
  y = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
  z = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
)
plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_markers(x = 1.5, y = 1.5) %>%
  add_markers(x = ~x, y = ~y, frame = ~z) %>%
  animation_button(font = list(color = "white",
                               family = "Aldhabi"),
                   bgcolor = "blue",   
                   bordercolor = "blue",
                   # color = "red"
                   # activebgcolor = "red"
                   )
```

Edit:
As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245078/change-button-font-color-on-hover-with-hover-color-declared-on-each-button-tag?rq=1) I tried this command but it didn't help either.

```
btn:hover {
  color:"red";
}
```

Comment: No quotes on “red” in css

Comment: Also, it would be background-color not just color.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you just do:

```
 .classname:hover{
      background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: I added this suggestion in my html specifications, but it didn't work - how do you exactly integrate this command? Could you maybe show it with the example from above? Thanks!

Comment: I never used plotly but found this... https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources

Comment: Thanks for this link but it didn't help either - I now found a workaround regarding the color scheme, so although the 'hovering' color stays the same at least it looks good.