# How do you change the link color of one specific link in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, colors

How do you change the color of a specific link on a post in WordPress? Do I just use CSS code right there in the post?

for example, this is what I did in the post:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><font color="FF00CC"></font>test</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><font color="FF00CC">test</font></a>
```

it didn't work

I don't know how to give it a class name because it's just a single word so I'm not sure I can target it in the custom CSS section.

do you know how to change the link's hover, active, and visited states too? The color that I selected for the whole WordPress site I have is different in this particular word and I'm not sure why either.

I have a class name on this entire post as a side note because I did other CSS customizations on it in the custom CSS section. I just want to target this one link on this page tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an inline CSS.

```
<a style="color: #FF00CC" href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
```

Comment: do you know how to add a color when hovering over this link? thanks!!

Comment: With JUST inline CSS, it's "impossible". You can check a complete explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Answer (score 2):

You may do well reading through the basics of web design, or at least browsing the [Basics of CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). You should avoid using inline CSS unless you specifically need to, especially if you intend to use [Pseudo-Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) such as `:hover`.

You may also consider reading over the basics of [Semantic HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5), because elements like [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) are obsolete and effectively unsupported.

Now to the root of your question, all you need to do is add a class to your link:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="test-link">Test</a>
```

Then in your Appearance > Customizer > Custom CSS you can target that with a very basic selector:

```
.test-link {
    color: #F0C;
}
```

Also, since it's being selected via CSS you can now use the `:hover` pseudo-class, which is something you can't do with inline CSS (you would have to use inline JavaScript, which is enormously overkill for something so trivial):

```
.test-link:hover {
    color: #0FC;
}
```

Take a look at the following snippet to see it in action.

```css
.test-link {
  color: #F0C;
}

.test-link:hover {
  color: #0CF;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com/" class="test-link">Test</a>
```