# How do I add a css pseudo rules in djangocms? I want to implement a hover effect

Tags: django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I want to change the opacity of a div when the mouse is hovered over the area so I can reveal some text  in djangocms.

When I add `.team-img:hover .overlay { opacity: .8; }` djangocms clears it when I save the changes because it confuses :hover for the definition of the property value

Djangocms gives an attribute field for the type of rule and a another field for the value. In the attribute field i wrote style and in the value field i wrote

```css
.team-img:hover .overlay { opacity: .8; }
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more context of where exactly you are adding the css in question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and should not add pseudo element styling inline. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033166/4654126).

For Django CMS the right place to put styling is the project's css file. In your case you should probably add:

```
.team-img:hover .overlay { opacity: .8; }
```

Then, you can add the **classes** in the attribute fields using the `class` attribute.

Probably even better, if you use the `djangocms-style` plugin, you can configure a style (`DJANGOCMS_STYLE_CHOICES` specifically) with the class properly set. See [this github repository](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style). This takes away the burden from the editors to remember the class names.