# How can I implement css hover effect in react inline-styling?

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

I am trying to implement a hover effect in the react component using react inline-styling.

```
const InfoWindow: React.FC<IInfoWindowProps> = ({ room }) => {

  const info_window_image = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "168px",
    background: `url(${room.pictures[0].image.large}) no-repeat`,
    backgroundSize: "contain",
    cursor: 'pointer'
  };

  return (
    <div className="info_window_container">
      <div style={info_window_image} />
    </div>
  )
};
```

div tag under **info_window_container** gets style object **info_window_image** .

I can successfully receive an image from API but I want to give zoom-in animation when the user hovers the image in the component.

I gave className to the div and styled in CSS file however it does not work. Styles I declared in CSS file do not render.

How can I make hover or focus effect in react-inline-styling?

Comment: You can't do `hover` with inline styles.

Comment: a look like question in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)