# How to move a background image on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a css file that has a background image that moves on hover

```
    .bg {
        width: 400px;
        height: 240px;
        margin: auto;
        background: url (....) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 100%;
        / * work with the background-size * /
        transition: background-size 1s ease-in-out;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba (0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    
    .bg: hover {
        background-size: 120% / * work with the background-size * /
    }
    
    .bg :: before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        background: rgba (0, 0, 0, .5);
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

It works great.

The problem is that if I set a nice background image in react it does not respond to me when hover

```
     <div
         class = "bg"
         style = {{
           background: `url (" ... ") no-repeat center center / 100% 100%`,
         }}
       >
```

I searched the net and found no answer
what can we do?

Comment: `: hover` is not valid syntax for a pseudo-selector. Remove the space.

Comment: Do you mean it changes the bg but not do the animation

Comment: You need to stop using so much extra whitespace in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div
     class = "bg"
     style = {{
       background: `url (" ... ") no-repeat center center / 100% 100%`,
     }}
   >
```

on hover just change background size with important!

```
.bg:hover {
  background-size: 120% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to `:hover` an inline style-element, as `:hover` is a pseudo-selector and only works inside the style sheet.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css) post on Stackoverflow. So I think it is more a problem with CSS than react which couldn’t be fixed.

Comment: It it possible to overwrite it with css !important; I have did in answer

Comment: Great to know – somehow I never had to use this case in particularly. As long you are not using !important everywhere this is a really good method! :)

Answer (score 0):

I maid small changes (remove spaces and code improvements) and it works fine and response on hover.

Here is my react component

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function Example() {

    return (
        <div className="bg"/>
    )
}
```

and styles.css

```
.bg {
    margin: auto;
    background: url("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: background-size 1s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.bg:hover {
    background-size: 120%
}

.bg::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```