# Adding css hover style without using external css file

Tags: reactjs

I've found some css styling that I would like to add to a Material-Table component in my React app, so it highlights the hovered row. See it below:

```
tr:hover {
  background: gray !important;
}
```

How can I apply this to my component without using an external css file? Is it using some inline styling, or useStyles or something else? I'm a bit weak on this area.

Comment: This post may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033166/6062364. Is says you should'nt use inline styling for pseudo selectors. You could simply write the style in a css file and import it in you component file.

Comment: Does the same apply to useStyles?

Comment: Yes, you can use `makeStyles` or `withStyles` to implement this on the table. Just forked an example of the MUI [table](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0bwj9?file=/demo.js).