# How can I change the hover style for inline CSS in a React page?

Tags: css, reactjs, button, hover

I changed my css to inline css. while i have to change the button:hover to the inline css, But that is not working. Is there any way to solve this?

```html
<button 
  style={{
    borderRadius: "10px",
    backgroundColor: "#004577",
    color: "#ffffff",
    border: "0px",
    width: "auto",
  }}
  className=" d-flex col-4 justify-content-center  p-2" 
  type="submit">
    Update profile
</button>
```

I tried but this is not working.

Comment: Hi @chandra mayou you could do something like this: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-style-hover-in-react/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  return (
    <button
      style={{
        borderRadius: "10px",
        backgroundColor: isHovered ? "#002744" : "#004577",
        color: "#ffffff",
        border: "0px",
        width: "auto"
      }}
      className="d-flex col-4 justify-content-center p-2"
      type="submit"
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      Update profile
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
You can watch instead with these 2 props if you hovered or left the element:

```
<button onMouseEnter={() => {console.log('hovered');}} onMouseLeave={() => {console.log('left');}} />
```

A similar ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-can-i-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Comment: But how can i write styles for the hover?

Comment: @ChandraMayou I have edited Diego's answer. by that you can apply styles on  hover

Answer (score 1):

For changing styles on hover, some modifications in [Diego Ammann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22172357/diego-ammann) Answer.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };
const non_hover_style= {
        borderRadius: "10px",
        backgroundColor:  "cyan",
        color: "#ffffff",
        border: "0px",
        width: "auto"
      }

const hover_style= {
        borderRadius: "10px",
        backgroundColor: "red" ,
        color: "#ffffff",
        border: "0px",
        width: "auto"
      }

  return (
    <button
      style={isHovered ? hover_style : non_hover_style }
      className="d-flex col-4 justify-content-center p-2"
      type="submit"
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      Update profile
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```