# Define element-level CSS that applies to pseudo-selector

Tags: css, inline, element, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

Is something like this...

```
<span style="this:hover{color:blue}">Turns blue on hover</span>
```

...possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not. Use a class or id and a separate stylesheet :)