# Can Reactjs programmatically handle :before?

Tags: css, less, reactjs

I somehow have to programmatically set the width of the `:before` for a `div`.

```
<div className="something" style={someStyle}> </div>
```

How can I define the `someStyle` so that the width of the `:before` of ``` .something``div ``` can change accordingly??

Comment: Pseudo elements cannot be styled with inline styles as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14141821/368697. You will have to style the `something` class name in a stylesheet with the `.something:before` selector. This is not a limitation of React but rather a design choice for HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pseudo elements cannot be styled with inline styles as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14141821/368697. You will have to style the `something` class name in a stylesheet with the `.something:before` selector. This is not a limitation of React but rather a design choice for HTML + CSS.

If you need to programmatically change the width of the pseudo `:before` element, it is probably more appropriate as a regular DOM element rendered by React.

Comment: @haohcraft, do you have an example on using :before, :after, + in reactjs ?

Answer (score 31):

Yes, you can programmatically change the value of pseudo-elements like ::before, ::after in react.

**Here is a trick.**

app.js

```
const widthVar = 34;
const someStyle = {
     "--width": widthVar
}
<div className="something" style={someStyle}> </div>
```

style.css

```
.something:before{
      width: var(--width),
      // remaining code
}
```

Comment: This one is actually good. I was looking for it, thank you.

Comment: @uhetz I am really glad you like this solution. Yesterday I was also figuring out any solution but none of them works for me.

Comment: If you're using Typescript, you'll need to extend the CSSProperties type from React before accessing the variable to make this work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65959390/868724

Comment: You saved me a considerable amount of time, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got insight from @am2505 to use CSS variables as it helped me however, this way avoids inline styling.

HTML
`<div className="something"> </div>`

CSS

```
:root {
--width: <yourDefaultValue>
}

.something:before{
      width: var(--width),
}
```

JS

```
const changeWidth=() => {
    let root = document.querySelector(':root');
      root.style.setProperty('--width', '<yourNewValue>px');
```

call the function at the event you want the width to change.
The changeWidth function can be further modified to dynamically work with state using conditional statements.