# How does this pseudo element work?

Tags: css

I don't want to modify the markup and I just want to know the reason behind the pseudo element that's how it works.

## [code demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rx8b25vy/)

```
div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 300px;
    
}
div:before{
    content: "";
    height: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}
```

> [image]

## and narrowing the browser:

> [image]

So, why just one line of paragraph is getting aligned? If you try to use `vertical-align: bottom;` then you can see it would be at bottom and all lines of the paragraph would be there.

But I'm just curious to know why just one line of them is working with vertical align?

Comment: _“So, why just one line of paragraph is getting aligned?”_ – _because_ the pseudo element is displayed as `inline-block`, which means it resides within a normal _line_ of text. _“If you try to use vertical-align: bottom; then you can see it would be at bottom and all lines of the paragraph would be there”_ – nope, at least not in my test in Chrome – only one line is displayed at the bottom _within_ the border, all the rest is displayed outside of the element in the overflow area.

Comment: yes, what I meant to say...

Comment: But only one line of the paragraph is getting aligned, why?

Comment: Nothing to do with the pseudo-element - a child element in the same location would behave the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141374/using-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-inline-css]

Comment: @BoltClock could you please give a demo without pseudo /

Comment: @Tanya Sinha: This question doesn't even use inline styles. What makes you think that could conceivably be a duplicate?

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal: https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/rx8b25vy/1

Comment: @BoltClock Hmmm, ok. But why is this so?

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Comment: _“But only one line of the paragraph is getting aligned, why?”_ – because the pseudo element is part of that line of “text” … same way, as if you had `<div><span>Fake pseudo</span> additional text …</div>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The height of your pseudo-element is 100% of the `div`. Since it is an inline-block `:before` pseudo-element, this increases the effective line height of the first line to 300px, while leaving the rest of the lines unaffected. The rest of the text on the first line is then affected by the `vertical-align: middle` on your pseudo-element, since it is on the same line as your pseudo-element. See [section 10.8 of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height).

If you change the line height of the `:first-line` pseudo-element instead of using a `:before` pseudo-element, you'll have [a similar effect](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/rx8b25vy/2):

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 300px;
}
div:first-line {
    line-height: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But the concept should be much clearer since you're actually styling the first line of text directly rather than using a pseudo-element to influence the first line box.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal What part of the answer don't you understand? If you can be a little more specific we might be able to add clarity :-)